# Range, Reverse, Sum!

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

Given a positive integer n as input, output the reversed range sum of n.

A reversed range sum is created by making an inclusive range up to n, starting with 1 and including n, reversing each of the numbers inside, and summing it.

**Example:**

Here is what would happen for an input of 10:

Range: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Reverse: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,01]` (1-char numbers reversed are themselves, 10 reversed is 01 or 1)

Sum: `46`

Numbers with 3+ digits are reversed the same way numbers with 2 digits are. For example, 1234 would become 4321.

**Test cases:**

```
Input -> Output

10 -> 46
5 -> 15
21 -> 519
58 -> 2350
75 -> 3147
999 -> 454545
```

Complete text cases to input of 999 can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/2TdCfeS4), thanks very much to @fireflame241.

Comment: More test case *results* (not numbered, sorry, but you can parse through and get their line number if you want): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/v8aByyrGUIXLOqZI5f9/AA "cQuents – Try It Online")

Comment: @StepHen >:D [Charcoal is faster](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWPOqY@alh2aPujxg3v96w7tPpR465zO0Hi63qA5Lldh3b//29paflftzjnv24iAA)

Comment: [Numbered](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9noWPGjecb3@/Z9mjxq1AJhwdWg2W2/V@z8pH63qA5Lmd59tBCoGSu4Do3E4FEG/J//8A)

Comment: [Relevant](http://oeis.org/A062918)

Comment: [OEIS A062918](https://oeis.org/A062918)

Comment: -1 because this is uninteresting. It seems like most, if not all, of the submissions are using the same approach. This challenge seems like a bunch of problems that have already been asked, just piped together with no obvious shortcuts.

Answer (score 17):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

#### Code

```
LíO
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5/Ba////zU0B)

#### Explanation

```
L       # Range
 í      # Reverse
  O     # Sum
```

Comment: dat explanation tho

Comment: @ETHproductions well `Reverse` should be `Reverse each` actually...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's not vectorized?

Comment: @ASCII-only 05AB1E vectorization is really 1 level deep, not ∞. Also just "reverse" is `R`, while `í` is "reverse each".

Answer (score 13):

## Bash + GNU utils, 24

```bash
seq $1|rev|paste -sd+|bc
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Nco7DoAgEAXAnlO8ws6QiAlR4mn4rNEGlN1YcXe0ceoJno@@lwohluiZcGaYCRazgV2xWDjnsCEVhQ@TQGsMf1ed6cZgWqWnXZ6FoDmNLcSeSqb@Ag).

#### Explanation

```bash
seq $1                    # range
      |rev                # reverse (each line)
          |paste -sd+|bc  # sum
```

Comment: Read from stdin for -3 bytes: `seq|rev|paste -sd+|bc`

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 20 bytes

```perl6
{(1..$_)».flip.sum}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##TY7dCoJAEIXv5ykGkVjR1lZbTaToIboMonQDwZ@l1SiiJ@oRuvPFrLGImIsZzvnOYbQ6ldHQGYXniGcpVFecZE2ucDncmODc3jn9kx/LQnPTVfdhJNatMi0u0e0fZVErw4jJmurA/G3u@k4KVLh5Qynocl@jOyZSODanb3i6QoZ2Ueuu9dBWF62yVuXo4A0QC4P0A/v4zh/gofURqeCnWnAfxIykeQSStpAQCDqkSEAu6ApCOYN4dEMxjyFJkjEhaV4)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{
   ( 1 .. $_ )\  # Range
   ».flip        # flip each value in the Range (possibly in parallel)
   .sum          # sum up the list
}
```

Comment: Is the 'possibly in parallel' required? Seems like you could get rid of a byte or two by omitting it.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes No. The `».flip` calls the `.flip` method on each of the values in the Range. The next shortest way to do this is `.map(*.flip)` which is 5 bytes more.

Comment: Oh, so the key part is "each", not "(possibly in parallel)". Might be worth splitting them out, then.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I'm not sure I know what you mean `».flip` is a hyper method call. While I can split up the `»` and `.flip` by using an unspace `\ ` like I did before it; that would make it harder to understand, as it would look like the end of a `qqww/ /` construct (`« a b "c d" »`).

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

```
f=n=>n&&+[...n+""].reverse().join``+f(n-1)
```

My favorite doubly-recursive solution is unfortunately 3 bytes longer:

```
f=n=>n&&+(g=x=>x?x%10+g(x/10|0):"")(n)+f(n-1)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>41</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
1$`¶
1+
$.&
%O^$`.

.+
$*
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLy5DLUCXh0DYuQyBPT41L1T9OJUGPiwsq@f@/oQGXKZeRIZepBZe5KZelpSUA) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 5 bytes thanks to @FryAmTheEggman. Saved 1 byte thanks to @PunPun1000. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1
1$`¶
```

Create a range from `1` to `n`.

```
1+
$.&
```

Convert back to decimal.

```
%O^$`.
```

Reverse each number.

```
.+
$*
```

Convert back to unary.

```
1
```

Sum and convert back to decimal.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Bah, I keep forgetting about that.

Comment: You don't need the `¶` in the `.+¶`  The match will match across lines

Comment: @PunPun1000 I did need it before FryAmTheEggman's fix!

Comment: I notice that ``O^$s`.`` to reverse the whole string also works.

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 63 bytes

```c
f(n){int t=0,c=n;for(;c;c/=10)t=t*10+c%10;return n?t+f(n-1):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxNDoIwEIXXcAqCIWkt6NSlQ/UibshAdRIdTC0rwtkr3by8n3yPuidROrDQexmnqv/FkefT65a8Er2yxCo6aMkJ@jkoJKSzs6Cji0cLhhoLGKa4BKnkHs0OdVZfAbeU0c/AorIZ9FoW@SAHdoDcW9jVmDwU37D3XtXN@JC69Yq1xrLYyi2li/0D)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

Can't compute higher terms than the recursion limit:

```python
f=lambda x:x and int(`x`[::-1])+f(x-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRocKqQiExL0UhM69EI6EiIdrKStcwVlM7TaNC11Dzf0ERUFwhTcPcVPM/AA)

Comment: You can use `import sys` and `sys.setrecursionlimit()` if you want to handle larger numbers, in the tio header.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ṛ€ḌS
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlmPmtY83NET/P//f3NTAA)**

#### How?

```
Ṛ€ḌS - Link: n
Ṛ€   - reverse for €ach (in implicit range)
  Ḍ  - convert from decimal list (vectorises)
   S - sum
```

Comment: I KNEW there had to be a way to use Range implicitly, +1

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 34 bytes

```
\n->sum$read.reverse.show<$>[1..n]
```

Simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>50</strike> 47 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [officialaimm!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59523/officialaimm)

```python
lambda n:sum(int(`i+1`[::-1])for i in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyMzr0QjIVPbMCHaykrXMFYzLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjT1Pzf0ERUJFCmoahgeZ/AA)

Comment: since it's python 2, `` instead of `str` saves 3 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 4 bytes

```
;\r$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/3zqmSOX/f0tLSwA)

### Explanation

```
       Implicit input n.
;      Series mode. Outputs the sum of the sequence from 1 to n.
 \r$   Each item in the sequence equals:
 \r    String reverse of
   $                     current index (1-based)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/), 4 bytes

```
⟦↔ᵐ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY/apjzcOkH7/39Dg//@AA)

#### Explanation

```
⟦↔ᵐ+
⟦        range from 0 to input
 ↔ᵐ      map reverse
   +     sum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>56</s> <s>41</s> 36 bytes

*15 bytes saved thanks to @fergusq*

```
{seq 1,_|parseInteger`$_`[::-1]|sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfyfFvO/uji1UMFQJ76mILGoONUzryQ1PbUoQSU@IdrKStcwtqa4NLf2f25iZl51tKWlZWxNWu1/AA)

This is an anonymous function that takes an integer from the input stream and outputs an integer to the output stream.

#### Explanation

```
{seq 1,_|parseInteger`$_`[::-1]|sum} Anonymous function
 seq 1,_                             Create a sequence 1 2 3 .. input and push each value to the stream
        |                            For each value in the stream:
                     `$_`             Cast it into a string
                         [::-1]       And reverse it
         parseInteger                 And parse the resulting string as an integer, while pushing the value to the stream
                               |sum  Sum all the values in the stream
```

Comment: You can save a lot of bytes by using `[::-1]` instead of reverse. Also ` `$_` ` is shorter than `_..""` and parentheses after parseInteger are not needed.

Comment: @fergusq Thanks for the tips, my Röda has gone a bit rusty :)

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>103</s> 97 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;r=>new int[r+1].Select((_,n)=>int.Parse(string.Concat((n+"").Reverse()))).Sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/BSsRADL3PV4Q9Zdg6sMdS24voSUG2Bw8iEse4DrTpOpmuSPHba1APYkIOeS95eYl6FqfM66xJDtB/aOGxcX@7cJ3krXFCI@uRIoMsLg6kCsfFaaGSIpym9Aw3lAT94q5miedJSmXVwZ7kwHs@cVbu5xHaNbed8DsYe5@3u4fQ88CxID5W4tvO4HBLNoxasrkIF5NEMlq2m40Pv0roLYLpoV8b92IfUHxF24VkwnAp88iZngYO3/dxV9V17c2cqelk8F1Ohe0zxn8GMXnfuM@fXL8A)

TIO link outputs all the results from 1 to 999, so feel free to check my work.

I expected this to be a bit shorter, but it turns out `Reverse()` returns an `IEnumerable<char>` instead of another string so I had to add some extra to turn it back into a string so I could parse it to an int. Maybe there's a shorter way to go from `IEnumerable<char>` to int correctly.

<s>Of minor note, this also uses the functions `Range()` `Reverse()` and `Sum()` all in order.</s>

-6 bytes thanks to TheLethalCoder

Comment: You don't need the trailing semi colon. I think using `new int[r]` and `.Select((_,n)=>...)` will save you bytes.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It takes `new int[r+1]` to get the right output since the index starts at 0, but it does still save a few bytes. RIP `Range()` though

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

*3 bytes golfed thanks to @Adám by converting to a tradfn from a train*

```apl
+/⍎⌽⍕⍳⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPd8b@2/qPevkc9ex/1Tn3Uu/lR31SQ8H8FMHDkMjTggjFN4SwjQ4SgBZxpjlBgaWkJAA)

```apl
⎕          Input (example input: 10)
⍳          Range; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
⍕          Stringify; '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'
⌽          Reverse; '01 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1'
⍎          Evaluate; 1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
+/         Sum; 46
```

Comment: To @Uriel & Cows quack about the chat question: Well, I did the Mathematics portion, in addition to that, I've been suspended from chat, hence my not responding in there.

Comment: 7 bytes: [`+/⍎⌽⍕⍳⎕`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPd8b@2/qPevkc9ex/1Tn3Uu/lR31SQ8H8FMHDkMjTggjFN4SwjQ4SgBZxpjlBgaWkJAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám Thanks for the tip. Removing the `¨` was clever :)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <del>56, 52, 41,</del> 39 bytes

```
->n{(1..n).sum{|i|i.to_s.reverse.to_i}}
```

## Ruby, 34 bytes (if lambda param is a string)

```
->n{(1..n).sum{|i|i.reverse.to_i}}
```

Thanks to @Unihedron for the second solution.

Comment: `->n{` works as well.

Comment: I have crafted a shorter program in the same tool (Ruby) that is different enough (it deals with input and output) to be its own submission, you can find it here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150636/21830

Comment: @Unihedron, haha, I didn't know Ruby is so crazy to allow string ranges. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, ruby also has nifty features like `?a..?z` and `?a1..?h8` (although you better be careful with the 2nd format :D)

Comment: Ranges has to either 1. (for start value) implement `succ` and 2. (if either start or end value does not implement `succ`) be numeric, so `int..string` will get rejected as "Bad value for range". The inverse is true (but alas there's no downto range), or `(?1..n)` can be used instead

Answer (score 4):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), <s>39</s> <s>37</s> 28 bytes

```
D@"O<C-V><C-A>0<ESC>V{g<C-A>:%!rev
v}gJS0<ESC>@"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/38VByV@M0UA6rDqd0UpVsSi1jKusNt0r2EDaQen/f0tLy/@6ZQA)

Tons of bytes saved thanks to some [great advice by user41805](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57622507#57622507)

#### Explanation

Step 1: build the range (with summing commands included)

```
D@"O<C-V><C-A>0<ESC>V{g<C-A>
D                               Delete the input number
 @"            <ESC>            Do that many times:
   O                              Insert a new line above
    <C-V><C-A>                    Write a <C-A> byte (\x01)
              0                   Followed by a 0
                    V{          Select all the lines just written
                      g<C-A>    Turn the numbers into an increasing range
```

Step 2: reverse each number

`:%!rev` (that's it)

This will produce a sequence of lines with the reversed number followed by `<C-A>`, which is the command to increase a value by the reversed number. Leading 0s actually move the pointer to the beginning of the line, so they are effectively ignored.

Step 3: sum them all up

```
v}gJS0<ESC>@"
v}               Select all the lines to the end of the file
  gJ             Join them
    S            Replace this line
     0<ESC>         with a 0
           @"    Execute the replaced line as commands
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 47 bytes

```
Tr[FromDigits@*Reverse/@IntegerDigits@Range@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/JL8kMSfarSg/1yUzPbOk2EErKLUstag4Vd/BM68kNT21CCoelJiXnuqgHKv2P6AoM69EwSFNwcHS0vI/AA)  (in order to work on mathics we need to replace "Tr" with "Total")

Comment: `Tr@*IntegerReverse@*Range`

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.*

```
õs xw
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9XMgeHc=&input=NzU=)

### Explanation

```
õs xw  Implicit input of integer U
õs     Create range [1,U] and map to strings
    w  Reverse each string
   x   Sum the array, implicitly converting to numbers.
```

## Old solution, 7 bytes

Keeping this since it's a really cool use of `z2`.

```
õs z2 x
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=9XMgejIgeA==&input=NzU=)

### Explanation

```
õs z2 x  Implicit input of integer U
õs       Create range [1,U] and map to strings
   z2    Rotate the array 180°, reversing strings
      x  Sum the array, implicitly converting back to integers
```

Comment: You know `z2` on a flat array is the same as `w`, righ... uhm... excuse my inadequacy at Japt...

Comment: 6 bytes: [`õ_swÃx`](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9V9zd8N4&input=NzU=) thanks to the new addition of `N.s(f)`.

Comment: Or even just [`õs xw`](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9XMgeHc=&input=NzU=) for 5 bytes.

Comment: @Shaggy I can't believe nobody mentioned that 5-byte solution until now... will edit in a bit. As for the 6-byte one, if that was added after this challenge was posted, I think that'd be non-competing.

Comment: @JustinMariner, neither can I! :D Although, it seems a shame to ditch that `z2` trick; that was pretty damn genius. Note that non-competing is [no longer a thing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/58974).

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Carlos Alejo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70347/carlos-alejo)

```
Ｉ∕…·⁰Ｎ«⁺ιＩ⮌Ｉκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy7CoQwEAB/JeUGI1wbLLWxOQ7/IMZFF3NR8mrEb1/vdGDKGbuYYDfjmD@BfILWxAQdFZoQem9djlRwMH5GeCnR@z2nd/6OGEBKJY4nqoCUuMsBC4aIz2aVf86fDbPWmuvCdXQX) Link is to verbose version.

### Explanation

```
Ｉ                  Cast
  ∕     «           Reduce
   …·⁰Ｎ            Inclusive range from 0 to input as number
         ⁺          Plus
          ι         i
           Ｉ⮌Ｉκ   Cast(Reverse(Cast(k)))
```

Comment: You can save a byte by dropping the last `»`. By the way, where in the Charcoal wiki is the `Reduce` operator documented?

Comment: Nowhere, it's an overload of the division one :| I can give you edit access if you want (sorry I'm too lazy to do it myself)

Comment: Also yeah I forgot why leaving out ending braces works lol

Comment: I would really like the Charcoal wiki to be a bit more documented, as there are still some working but hidden features. If you grant me edit access I'll do my best to document them. Example: how can the `Modulo` operator be used to format strings in Charcoal?

Comment: So why do you need the `«`? You don't need it for `Map`...

Comment: @Neil Because otherwise it's treated as normal divide since it's then a valid expression. Should I have another custom operator instead (btw this is the same for any (`⊙`) and all (`⬤`) even though they're not overloads :| sorry i'll change them if you think it's going to have a big effect)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo I've had a bit of free time so I've started documenting stuff, hope you like it!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo it's python style modulo so the format is exactly the same as with Python, also sent invite to what I think it's your GitHub

Comment: @ASCII-only Wait until I start reporting bugs...

Comment: Well that's good as well isn't it, it means Charcoal will be less buggy

Comment: @CarlosAlejo pls accept github invite tyvm

Comment: @ASCII-only I didn't receive any invitation. My Github account is `charliealejo`.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo done (also i invited "Carlos Alejo" who joined 13 days ago, I thought it was you)

Answer (score 3):

### C++, 146 bytes

```cpp
#include<string>
using namespace std;int r(int i){int v=0,j=0;for(;j<=i;++j){auto t=to_string(j);reverse(t.begin(),t.end());v+=stoi(t);}return v;}
```

Comment: Good job! You can spare some bytes by removing the header and putting "using namespace std" (check here https://tio.run/#cpp-gcc). I also think you could replace "auto t" with just "t" (?)

Comment: Yeah, koita_pisw_sou is right about the first part. But you need the `auto`.

Comment: @koita_pisw_sou Do you mean that i can exclude the header directive from the byte count ? Same for the namespace ? `auto` keyword is needed

Comment: Yes, check the link I sent

Comment: (Whoops, I am not sure about the removing the header!) But I was referring to `using namespace std;` saving bytes.

Comment: You can use `#import<string>` to save a byte, but the bytes for the header still count.

Comment: @KarlNapf From what i read, the `import` statement is non standard and doesn't work the same way between GCC and VC++

Comment: Regarding code golfing, you're free to chose a specific compiler/interpreter and/or a specific implementation of a given language. Writing standard code shouldn't be a concern, only the bytecount should. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>7 6</s> 3 bytes

```
ṁ↔ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxkdtUx7uWPz//39LS0sA)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
  ḣ  -- With the list [1..N] ..
ṁ    -- .. do the following with each element and sum the values:
 ↔   --    reverse it
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>29 27</s> 22 + 1 (`-p`) = 23 bytes

```perl
map$\+=reverse,1..$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlRtu2KLUstag4VcdQT08lvrb6/39Dg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA)

Comment: 26 bytes: `map$r+=reverse,1..<>;say$r`.

Comment: Got it down even further using `-p`

Answer (score 3):

### [Magneson](https://github.com/UnderMybrella/Magneson), 102 bytes

[image: Source]

That's not very visible, so here's a scaled up version (Note: Won't actually run, and still isn't very pretty)

[image: Display Purposes Only]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://storage.googleapis.com/brella-archives/Code%20Golf/Magneson/range_reverse_sum_visible.png))</sub>

Magneson operates by parsing an image and evaluating commands from the colours of the pixels it reads. So stepping through the image for this challenge, we have:

- `R: 0, G: 1, B: 1` is an integer assignment command, which takes a string for the variable name and the value to assign. We'll use this to store the sum total.
- `R: 0, G: 1, B: 0` is a prebuilt string with the value `VAR_1` (Note: This is only while we're asking for a string; the colour code has a separate function when used elsewhere).
- `R: 3, G: 0, B: 0` is a raw number. Magneson handles standard numbers by requiring the Red component to be exactly 3, and then forms a number by using the blue value directly *plus* the green value multiplied by 256. In this case, we're just getting the number 0.
- `R: 0, G: 1, B: 1` is another integer assignment command. This time, we're storing an iteration variable, to keep track of which number we're on
- `R: 0, G: 1, B: 1` is a prebuilt string with the value `VAR_2` (Once more, only when we need a string)
- `R: 3, G: 0, B: 0` is the number 0, once more. Onto the interesting bits now.
- `R: 1, G: 0, B: 0` indicates the start of a loop. This takes a number and loops the following snippet of code that many times.
- `R: 2, G: 0, B: 0` is the STDIN function, or at least it is when we need a number. This reads a line of input from the console and turns it into a number, since we asked for a number.
- `R: 0, G: 8, B: 0` starts off our looping code, and it is an additive command. This adds a number to an integer variable, and so takes a string for the variable name, and the number to add.
- `R: 0, G: 1, B: 1` is the prebuilt string for `VAR_2`, which is our iteration variable.
- `R: 3, G: 0, B: 1` is a raw number, but this time it's the number 1.
- `R: 0, G: 8, B: 0` is another addition command.
- `R: 0, G: 1, B: 0` is the string for `VAR_1`, which is our sum total.
- `R: 0, G: 3, B: 0` is a function that reverses a string. In the context of asking for a number, it then converts the reversed string to a number.
- `R: 0, G: 2, B: 1` is an integer retrieval command, and will retrieve the number stored in a provided variable. In the context of asking for a string (such as from the reverse command), it converts the number to a string.
- `R: 0, G: 1, B: 1` is the name `VAR_2`; our iteration variable.
- `R: 1, G: 0, B: 1` is the marker to end the loop, and go back to the start of the loop if the criteria isn't met (so if we need to keep looping). Otherwise, proceed onwards.
- `R: 0, G: 0, B: 1` is a very simple println command, and takes a string.
- `R: 0, G: 2, B: 1` retrieves an integer from a variable
- `R: 0, G: 1, B: 0` is the name of our sum total variable, `VAR_1`

All in all, the program:

- Assigns the value 0 to `VAR_1` and `VAR_2`
- Loops from 0 to a number provided in STDIN

  - Adds one to `VAR_2`
  - Adds the integer value of reversing `VAR_2` to `VAR_1`
- Prints the contents of `VAR_1`

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
ri){sW%i}%:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyhTs7o4XDWzVtVK@/9/QwMA)

-1 thanks to [Business Cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53880/business-cat).

Explanation:

```
ri){sW%i}%:+
r            Get token
 i           To integer
  )          Increment
   {sW%i}    Push {sW%i}
    s         To string
     W        Push -1
      %       Step
       i      To integer
         %   Map
          :+ Map/reduce by Add
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation? I don't understand CJam (nor GolfScript). But MY beat two (albeit ancient in terms of golf-langs) golfing languages!

Comment: @Zacharý done...

Comment: You don't need the `,`

Comment: @BusinessCat Ohhh used too much to GolfScript apparently...

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 97 bytes

```
IntStream.range(1,n+1).map(i->Integer.valueOf(new StringBuffer(""+i).reverse().toString())).sum()
```

---

**EDIT**

As per the comment of [`Kevin Cruijssen`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen), I would like to improve my answer.

## Java 8, 103 bytes

```
n->java.util.stream.LongStream.range(1,n+1).map(i->new Long(new StringBuffer(""+i).reverse()+"")).sum()
```

Comment: `Integer.valueOf` can be golfed to `new Integer`, and `.reverse().toString()` can be golfed to `.reverse()+""`. Also, you must include the required imports and lambda parameters, like `java.util.stream.IntStream` and `n->` before it. And you can also golf `IntStream` & `Integer` to `LongStream` and `Long`. The final answer will be `n->java.util.stream.LongStream.range(1,n+1).map(i->new Long(new StringBuffer(""+i).reverse()+"")).sum()` (**103 bytes** - Your current answer with added import and lambda parameter would be **117 bytes**.) Still +1, nice answer!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you for your valuable inputs. I'll update my answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 26 bytes

```
&IFLPWaSD$|~rlMFa*+|&+&|&h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X83TzScgPDHYRaWmrijH1y1RS7tGTVutRg0oZ2gAAA)

### Explanation

```
&I                      &h < register init, read "n"; print register (h = n;)
  FLP                  |   < For loop, do "n" times for each x in [1] to [n]
     WaSD$|                < modpow "x" to digits: [123] [3 12] [3 2 1] [3 2 1 0]
           ~rlMFa*+|       < Ditch zero, reverse stack, build the number back
                    &+&    < register += final x
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `s`, 2 bytes

```
ƛṘ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C6%9B%E1%B9%98&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Comment: [Here's a test suite if you're interested.](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%E2%97%81&inputs=&header=%CE%BB&footer=%3B%E2%88%91%3B%0A%0A%E2%9F%A810%7C5%7C21%7C58%7C75%7C999%E2%9F%A9%20%24%20z%28nh%E2%82%B4%60%20-%3E%20%60%E2%82%B4nt%2C%29)

Comment: As impressive as this is, I think flags should be included in the bytecount, as the program would not have worked this way if it wasn't for the flag

Comment: @Dion it was decided that [flags don't have to be byte count](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14337/78850) over on meta. If I didn't have that policy backing me up, vyxal wouldn't have flags at all.

Comment: [new codepage version](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C6%9B%E1%B9%98&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Comment: Idea: allow usage of older versions on the webpage and add that as a link parameter

Answer (score 3):

## vim, <strike>49</strike> 46 bytes

```
A@q<ESC>0"bDa1<ESC>qqYp<C-a>q@bdk:%s/$/+
:%!rev
xVGJ:%!bc
```

`<ESC>` is 0x1b,
`<C-a>` is 0x01,
`<NL>` is 0x0a.

### Annotated

```
A@q<ESC>0"bD  # put {N}@q (run macro q N times) in register b
a1<ESC>       # buffer now contains "1"
qqYp<C-a>q    # store macro that copies and increments the last line in register q
@bd1k         # run {N} times, then delete the extra lines
              # (can't just run {N-1} times, or it won't handle N=1 correctly)
:%s/$/+<NL>   # append + to each line
:%!rev<NL>    # reverse each line
x             # delete leading +
VGJ           # join lines
:%!bc<NL>     # sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39GhUNpAKckl0VC6sDCygLHQISkl20q1WF9FX5vLSlWxKLWMqyLM3QvITErm@v/f0AAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 59 bytes

```
=LET(y,COLUMN(A:O),SUM((0&MID(SEQUENCE(A1),y,1))*10^(y-1)))
```

Explanation

```
=LET(
y,COLUMN(A:O)                           'y = [1..15] horz.; Excel is accurate to 15 places
SUM((0&MID(SEQUENCE(A1),y,1))*10^(y-1)) 'final result
           SEQUENCE(A1)                 '[1..A1] vertical
    (0&MID(            ,y,1))           'array of individual digits; 0& is to avoid errors on blank cells 
                             *10^(y-1)  'multiply 2nd column by 10, 3rd 100, etc.
SUM(                                  ) 'sum the array
```

Comment: Just an FYI, your answers are popping up in the Low Quality Posts [review queue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts) as their length catches the system filter. I'd suggest adding in a brief explanation in order to avoid this :)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.  I will start adding some explanations.

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 8 bytes

```
{Ø.in}S+
```

### Explained

```
{Ø.in}S+
{    }S # Create a stack in range 0 through the implicit input, using the function defined
 Ø.     # Append nothing, stringifying the number
   i    # Reverse the string
    n   # Convert back to a number
       +# Get the sum of the stack, and output implicitly.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/7/68Ay9zLzaYO3///8bGgAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>8</strike> 6 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to [FryAmTheEggman!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman)</sup>

```
sms_`h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzi3OD4BSBsaAAA)

Comment: 1 byte longer version, ``sms_`dS``, that does not abuse implicit `U` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 66 bytes

```
time {incr s [regsub ^0+ [string rev $n] ""];incr n -1} $n
puts $s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCoAgEAXQfaf4iLsItG1HEVskgwg1hDO2ic5u0fbxNO1dSMGYne9aDsJdOFUIQqUsbcPqRgTRWjij0gXLEcbE5W@MyT8fDWdTgZXeXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 4 bytes

```
Δ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//9yUD3MnrNYEEmv@/zc0AAA)

## Explanation

```
Δ )              for each element 1 to n (outputs list)
                reverse 
                sum
```

Comment: Alternative solution: `Ψ` (create inclusive range, reverse each element, sum)

Comment: @Okx didn't know that the `Ψ` token existed! would have definitely used that in hindsight. real nice

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>80</s> <s>78</s></sub> 49 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediate Window function that takes input expected type `Integer` from range `[A1]` determines all of the values that fall within the range `1:[A1]`, and outputs the sum of the reversed values to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To[A1]:s=s+Val(StrReverse(Str(i))):Next:?s
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 71 bytes

```c
q(n,x,p){p=n?q(n/10,x*10+n%10):x;}f(w,a,e){for(a=0;w;)a+=q(w--,0);e=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEEDRfU8RCoUZM8EUXDkEL@ImtI0OaEyLkEDp2WPt3z34g3kMQ60zRCqUcE0u3nace0vl1Fsdu97itfAWIJOnCdfwWcA7y5nRazdDNoYs8uQ8b/XtJQKujdqT@FWinLJ8MD/lNYHWggf/pWV/ArTdZUTVjffYklAAQeSm2eoP)

Comment: Wait... what? How `f()` returns its result without any `return` statement? Does the `e=a` instruction manipulates the registers in such a way that the result is stored in the same register than the one used by returned values?

Answer (score 2):

### [TXR Lisp](http://nongnu.org/txr): <s>62</s> 56 bytes:

```
(opip(range 1)(mapcar[chain tostring reverse toint])sum)
```

Interactive:

```
1> (opip(range 1)(mapcar[chain tostring reverse toint])sum)
#<intrinsic fun: 0 param + variadic>
2> [*1 10]
46
3> [*1 999]
454545
```

The following 44 byte expression, inspired by the [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) solution, is possible; however, it requires the `sum` macro to be defined:

```
1> (defmacro sum (var from to expr)
      (with-gensyms (accum)
        ^(for ((,var ,from) (,accum 0))
              ((<= ,var ,to) ,accum)
              ((inc ,accum ,expr) (inc ,var)))))
sum
2> (do sum x 1 @1 (toint(reverse(tostring x))))
#<interpreted fun: lambda (#:arg-01-0171 . #:rest-0170)>
3> [*2 10]
46
4> [*2 999]
454545
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 50 bytes

```
lambda n:sum(int(str(n)[::-1])for n in range(n))
```

Quite close to idiomatic Python code, and honestly I don't really see much room for improvement.

Comment: Use n surrounded by backticks instead of `str(n)` for a nice save

Comment: Backticksyntax is Python 2 only.
Plus, the answer is off by 1.. it should be range(n+1)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <del>38</del> 35 bytes

Similar to [the previous Ruby solution,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137070/21830)
 but a full program and also shorter (for less than an hour)!

```ruby
p (?1..gets).sum{|x|x.reverse.to_i}
```

Shortened by 3 bytes thanks to [user akostadinov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53829/akostadinov)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DB3lCvtKAkXyM9taRYU6@4NLe6pqKmQq8otSy1qDhVryQ/PrP2/39LS0sA)

### Explanation

```ruby
p             # Inspect and print. Written as infix notation to avoid using ()
(?1..gets)    # All strings from "1" to "input", based on successive string format
  .sum{|x|    # Enumerable -> Map to value -> Sum by value
      x.reverse.to_i
  }
```

Comment: you can do `(?1..gets).sum{...})`

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 7 bytes

```
@…)¦v¦Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3@FRwzLNQ8vKDi07t/j/f0tLSwA)

Range, Reverse, and sum!

```
@             # push an input. stack: n
 …            # generate range. stack: [0...n-1]
  )¦          # map over the list with increment. stack: [1...n]
    v¦        # map over the list with reverse. stack: [1...n], but all digitally reversed
      Σ       # sum the list; output TOS.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 52 bytes

```
lambda n:sum(int(str(n+1)[::-1])for n in range(n))
lambda n:sum(int(f'{n+1}'[::-1])for n in range(n))
```

The second is equivalent to the first.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 7 bytes

```
SF`_b)s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6jMTv3/P9gtIT5Js/j/f0MDAA)

```
S       -   range(1, input)
 F   )  -  for i in ^:
  `     -     str(i)
   _    -    reversed(^)
    b   -   int(^)
     s  - sum(^)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
:VPUs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yosILT4/39DAwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>89</s> 75 bytes

```r
sum(scan(t=sapply(1:scan(),function(x)intToUtf8(rev(utf8ToInt(c(x,'')))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V6M4OTFPo8S2OLGgIKdSw9AKzNfUSSvNSy7JzM/TqNDMzCsJyQ8tSbPQKEot0ygFMkLyPfNKNJI1KnTU1TUh4L@pxX8A)

Thanks to JayCe and Dominic van Essen for the golfs.

Comment: I know it's an old one but what about [this for 82 bytes?](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V6O4pKgkP1OjOLGgIKdSw9CqODkxT0NTJ600L7kkMz9Po0KzuiLaINZWXd06M68kJD@0JM1Coyi1TKMUyAjJ98wrASrR1KzV1DE00NT8b2rxHwA)

Comment: or even [this for 75 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V6M4OTFPo8S2OLGgIKdSw9AKzNfUSSvNSy7JzM/TqNDMzCsJyQ8tSbPQKEot0ygFMkLyPfNKNJI1KnTU1TUh4L@pxX8A)?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen thanks!

Comment: @JayCe Doesn't seem like you're active any longer, but thank you for the golf, and apologies I didn't respond sooner!

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 7 bytes

```
sms_`dS
```

Explanation

```
sms_`dSQ  Q added implicitly
s         Sum of
 m        map
  s_`d    integer representation of reversal of string representation
          to
      SQ  Range from 1 to input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
ř₫Ʃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MxHTauPrfz/39AAAA)

The characters perform the following operations: range, reverse, sum.

Comment: Dammit. You beat me to it. +1

Comment: @mudkip201 Yeah I feel like its almost a race to see who can get the most trivial arithmetic challenges answered

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｒ｛ŗ±┤］∑
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjMyJXVGRjVCJXUwMTU3JUIxJXUyNTI0JXVGRjNEJXUyMjEx,i=OTk5,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua (59 bytes)

```lua
function r(u)return u<1 and 0 or(u..""):reverse()+r(u-1)end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 43 bytes

```powershell
1.."$args"-join'+'|% t*y|%{$s=$_+$s}
$s|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NbsJADITv@xQW2hRSAmKBLc0BCYl7W4ljhVBJXX6UEBpnBVWSZ0/tpBTvZTw738jn9IIZ7TGOa/0FcyhqMxx29Ee2o87gmB5O3X639CB//Cm9QtNcb/qaKqWpPOC1rpRa9FTQMyMIYPrks7SsjBU1NiytCRv3mfV4YkeyzCQzMdOZLGEYCmvl@cqHEjwoFPDok0sC0Hg9Y5TjJx@nN@1HhuTinI0Hvllijf3@tlo6ytPkdXtkYr1oa2RWLoqQSCr@2AF@36v/cy8u2WImsVtpSyd3snErVdW/)

This script converts a range `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` to the reversed string `01+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1` and evaluates the string

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 127 bytes

```
def f(n):
 s=0
 for i in range(1,n+1):
  r=""
  k=str(i)
  for j in range(0,len(k)):
   r=r+k[len(k)-1-j]
  s+=int(r)
 return s
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 81 bytes

```java
long g(int n){return n<1?0:new Long(""+new StringBuffer(""+n).reverse())+g(n-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Ra4MwFIXf9ysugpDQVExb19lOBnve03wce0hrFDuNklwdQ/ztLqYddQmBm5N7z/lyEb1YN61Ul@xrOlfCGHiXvdRGpl0Nw1Q1qoCClApB0UFL7LQC9cxfwoOS3/Bmn4nnreY6RV2q4rXLc6mdRgN9tSKUrgqi1pwexwmg1WUvUIJBgeUZ@qbMAKXBawoDl4kUhgewy900JDBn3NkIDawlPbqe9MegrIOmw8CaK8yJ558OkBM/o3bSz3zlMdBJgmwO0G5stKftTpVFWJLUolTk@pePTxC6MH8kjpGHDHaPt1ynRAx4tBQ2nEHE4389Tww22yhcans7uOW7/VKL49jaR/O@MY7TLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn) `-x`, [4 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
P▀g³
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=filALjw=&input=NQoxMAoyMQo1OAo3NQo5OTk=&flags=eA==)

## Explained

Unpacked: `~)@.<`

```
    ~    One-range to
      _  Input; implied
  )
@        Map with
  .<     Reverse fix
      Implicit sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), <s>72</s> 70 bytes

```
l=floor(logx)
f(y)=∑_{x=1}^y∑_{n=0}^lmod(floor(x/10^n),10)10^{l-n}
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aj4ixkxvbs)

*-2 bytes thanks to Aiden Chow*

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 39 bytes

```factor
[ [1..b] [ >dec reverse dec> ] map Σ ]
```

[image: An image of running the above code in Factor's REPL]

Using build 2166 for the somewhat recent addition of [>dec](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-__gt__dec,math.parser.html).

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 7 bytes

```
ro)<-++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@U@b8oX9NGV1v7/39DAwA)

```
ro  # Range
)<- # Reverse
++  # Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
{+/.'|'$1+!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rW1tdTr1FXMdRWrKjl4kpTMDRQUNBX0LVTMDED8kwVoDxDUyDPyBDKMzW0BElaQLlGxqYGQL65KZRvbGhiDuRbWlpCjTIFQQCgNBTK)

*-1 byte thanks to coltim*

Comment: You could use `.'` instead of `\`I$` to save a byte. A couple more could be saved by making this tacit, i.e. [`+/.'|'$1+!:`](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJxLs9LW11OvUVcx1Fa04uJKUzA0UFDQV9C1UzAxA/JMFaA8Q1Mgz8gQyjM1tARJWkC5RsamBkC+uSmUb2xoYg7kW1paQo0yBUEAI7kTlA==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

```julia
!x=sum(Meta.parse∘join∘digits,1:x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBDoIwFET3PcWXVZsgoUDFmsDehWcwTajmk1pIWxKO4BE8nxepFGcW85KZGReDiq8xHtbOLy9600EVs3Jef9@fcUK7xYBPDD7nl5XFx@QAAS04rQaDVnvKCGxSOdyhg/1a0KsNOfjZYKCYQwbHHjL2H84ObTCWKuh6OChGtB0iL9OkORGRkgtS8QSCSyLOiapalKTd25o3LZFS7g@R/AM)

this works because `digits` returns an array with the digits starting with the least significants first (`digits(123) == [3, 2, 1]`)

##### alternative, also 38 bytes (but more chars and not as nice)

```julia
!x=sum(@.parse(Int,join(digits(1:x))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCoMwFET3OcXXVQJWjJraFJRue4oSMC1f0ihJBG@fmnRmMQMzb9kNKn7EWByj37/0UW/KeU2fNlTLipbO@MHgKb8f7FR8rw4Q0ILTajZotaeMwClVwQtGyHSdcfCbwUCxghIuE5Tsf9wc2mAsVTBOUChGtJ0jb9KlvxKRkgvS8lQEl0TcUms70ZAhrx3vByKlzIRI/gE)

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 16 bytes

```ruby
:+|:sum+(S|:~|Z)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWG6y0a6yKS3O1NYJrrOpqojQhwisKFNyiLS0tYyHcBQsgNAA)

### Explanation

Same idea as the Ruby answers but J-uby helps us out with some handy shortcuts.

```
:+ | :sum + (S | :~ | Z)

:+ |                      # Make range 1..n, then
     :sum + (          )  # Sum of items...
             S |          #   Converted to string, then
                 :~ |     #   Reversed, then
                      Z   #   Converted to int
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 68 bytes

```
1:{:})?^:9)?v:1+!
a:v?(1:[2$0:<.17-%1:,a}+*a{%
0.>~]$d
=?n+a3.>~{~l1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39Cq2qpW0z7OylLTvszKUFuRK9GqzF7D0CraSMXAykbP0FxX1dBKJ7FWWyuxWpXLQM@uLlYlhcvWPk870RjIqa7LMfz//79umZEhAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õÈìÔ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9cjs1A&input=MTA)

```
õÈìÔ     :Implicit input of integer
õ        :Range [1,input]
 È       :Map
  ì      :  Convert to digit array
   Ô     :  Reverse and implicitly convert back
         :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `+`, \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.29 bytes

```
R.rS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSStlLsgqWlJWm6FkuC9IqCIUyoyIJFhgYQFgA)

##### Explanation

```python
R.rS  # Implicit input
      # + flag adds one
R     # Range
 .r   # Reverse each
   S  # Sum
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
RDUḌS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/IJfThjp7g////GxkCAA)

```
R      ' [R]ange
 D     ' Integer -> [D]ecimal
  U    ' [U]pend (vectorized reverse?)
   Ḍ   ' [Ḍ]ecimal -> Integer
    S  ' [S]um
```

Comment: Shouldn't you make it `[U]pend` for completion's sake?

Comment: You right, all better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src), 11 bytes

```
iC4ǵ'ƒ⇹(Σ↵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9tef//8J2Vq2lDNMe1J8aS4oe5KM6j4oa1//8xMA)

### How?

- input as integer
- `i` [1 ... pop()] inclusive
- `C4ǵ'` push the string `'\x4C'` (The reverse command (`⌽`), which works on numbers)
- `ƒ` as a function
- `⇹` mapped over the argument (pushes a function)
- `(` apply the function
- `Σ` sum
- `↵` output with a new line

MY is capable of something, woohoo!

Comment: >_> unimplemented codepage

Comment: ...I just have to ask, why did you rearrange ASCII for your codepage? :P

Comment: I started with the functions, rather than the codepage, and I want the cp to be organized as heck (Nilads, Monads, Dyads, Triads). The unimplemented codepage is there so even readable at all.

Comment: Also, what do you expect from a language that has `12-` result in `1` rather than `-1`?

Comment: MY's codepage is now implemented, and MY is finally on TIO!

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 31 bytes

```
ns[l1-s]pr[s>lSrJs>l<p<p]>>r&+u
```

[Try it online!](http://lylang.herokuapp.com/?program=ns[l1-s]pr[s%3ElSrJs%3El%3Cp%3Cp]%3E%3Er%26%2Bu&input=75)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript,<s>89</s> <s>77</s> 72 bytes

*saved 12 bytes thanks to @Justin Mariner*

*saved 5 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```
n=>-eval(`-'${[...[...Array(n+1).keys()].join`'-'`].reverse().join``}'`)
```

#### Explanation:

`[...Array(n+1).keys()]` creates an array from 0 to n.

``` .reverse(‌).join`` ```  reverses every value.

`` .join`'-'` `` and `` eval(`-'{stuff}'`) `` subtracts the values in order, producing the negative of the answer.
`-` negates the negative to a positive.

Comment: You can use `[...Array(n)]` to avoid `fill()` and can combine both `map`s: ```n=>eval([...Array(n)].map((_,a)=>+(++a+"").split``.reverse().join``).join`+`)```. Be careful coping that since SE adds unprintable chars to break code lines.

Comment: It's quicker to join the array first, then reverse it, as that saves you from converting the numbers to strings: ```n=>eval([...[...Array(n+1).keys()].join`+`].reverse().join``)```.

Comment: @Neil doesn't work for 999(produces 4153), probably because of octal literals getting added

Comment: Bah, stupid octal literals. Best I can do in that case is ```n=>-eval(`-'${[...[...Array(n+1).keys()].join`'-'`].reverse().join``}'`)```.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 43 bytes

```
n->sum(i=1,n,fromdigits(Vecrev(digits(i))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYfBCsIwEAV/5dHTBjZgBLE5tJ/hpXgo2pSFdl3SWvDrYwTnMjM2ZvGzlYQORX2/vVeSLrByyq/1KbPsG92mR54O@p@4ShnNlg8pfA/LonvN5jcNEqlzjCGcGBfGOVS1jGvtGOPdlS8)

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 19 bytes

```
[:|_F!a$|p=p+!A!}?p
```

### Explanation

```
[:|     FOR a = 1 to n (read from cmd line)
_F   |      FLIP and assign to A$
  !a$        a string cast of our loop counter
p=p+!A!    increment p with A$ cast back to number
}           NEXT
?p         Print the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://swift.org/blog/swift-4-0-release-process/), <s>63</s> 61 bytes

```swift
{v in(1...v).reduce(0,{$0+Int(String("\($1)".reversed()))!})}
```

[**Try it online!**](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/598f3e52de80147f1a9d2351)

---

## Explanation

- `{v in}` - Creates an anonymous (lambda-like) function with a parameter `v`.
- `(1...v)` - Inclusive range from `1` to `v` (although it kind of breaks the rules of logic).
- `Int(String("\($1)".reversed()))` - Reverses the Number by converting it to a String, returning `ReverseCollection<String>`. That cannot be casted directly to an integer (Swift borked types!), so we have to cast it to String again, before making the conversion to an Integer.
- `reduce(0,{$0+...})` - Sums the mapped range.

Answer (score 0):

## [LOGO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fmslogo/), 33 bytes

```
[reduce "+ map "reverse iseq 1 ?]
```

There is no "Try it online!" link because all online LOGO interpreter does not support template-list.

That is a template-list (equivalent of lambda function in other languages).

Usage:

```
pr invoke [reduce[?+reverse ?2]iseq 1 ?] 10
```

(`invoke` calls the function, `pr` prints the result)

prints `46`.

Explanation:

LOGO stores numbers as words, therefore apply `reverse` on a number reverse the digits in that number.

`reduce "f [a b c d e]` (where `[a b c d e]` is a list) will calculate `f(a, f(b, f(c, f(d, e))))`. So `reduce "+ list` will calculate sum of values of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3, 98 bytes**

```
func f(a:Int)->Int{return (0...a).map{Int(String(String($0).characters.reversed()))!}.reduce(0,+)}
```

Comment: [77 bytes: `{a in(1...a).map{Int(String(String($0).characters.reversed()))!}.reduce(0,+)}`](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/598f3bddde80147f1a9d234f).

Comment: Also `String($0)` can be `"\($0)"` to save a couple of bytes too.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 53 bytes

```powershell
(1.."$args"|%{-join"$_"["$_".length..0]})-join'+'|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT09JJbEovVipRrVaNys/M09JJV4pGkTo5aTmpZdk6OkZxNZqgqXUtdVrMlMr/v//b2lpCQA)

Literal translation of the specification. Creates a range with `..`, reverses each by using string manipulation and `-join`ing them back into a single number, then `-join`s each number together with a `+` and piping that to `iex` (short for `Invoke-Expression` and similar to `eval`).

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 15 bytes

```
~),{`-1%~}%{+}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05TpzpB11C1rla1WrtW6/9/QwMA)

Explanation:

```
~),{`-1%~}%{+}* Input all at once
~               Eval
 )              Increment
  ,             Exclusive range
   {     }      Push block
    `            Repr
     -1          -1
       %         Every xth element
        ~        Eval
          %     Map
           { }  Push block
            +    Add
              * Reduce
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 39+1 bytes

```php
while($i++<$argn)$s+=strrev($i);echo$s;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 110 bytes

```rust
|x:i64|(1..x+1).map(|v|format!("{}",v).chars().rev().collect::<String>().parse::<i64>().unwrap()).sum::<i64>()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LDoMgEEXX@hWjK0gNqU1f0tdH9AsIgZZE0CBaE/Xb6dhFNzNzTyYn1/ddiNqBFcYRClOa1CqAvsV55Oa4n0nJ2LgpKbOiJfMw68ZbETKST0teDJTJt/AdocyrAads6lrJwPn1GbxxrzuyFh8UErStsXcfjypKWdfbP47JJU3QDSMYB4OSGSm3BRwK2JW4zgWc8K6q6lcxaVEearfW4A8sApqMlKJiSZf4BQ)

I like Rust, but it is not a very efficient language for golfing!

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 62 bytes

```
(loop as i to(read)sum(parse-integer(reverse(format()"~d"i))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYpBDoAwCMC@suwEBx@w5xCHhmQ6AtOjX0d6a9N9iGuAmtwrYMyphbxIWROMqaM/FyiZ85YDn2yZX06HY9pFC7B@vQomgdFa@wE)

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 46 bytes

```
arg n
s=0
do i=1 to n
  s=s+reverse(i)
  end
say s
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 3, <s>83</s> 68 characters

<s>let f={n in Array(1...n).reduce(0){$0+Int(String("($1)".characters.reversed()))!}}</s>

```
{(1...$0).reduce(0){$0+Int(String("\($1)".characters.reversed()))!}}
```

This would probably be shortened by Swift 4's new `String` and `Character` handling.

Comment: You do not need to include `let f=` in the byte count. That saves 6 bytes.

Comment: You also do not need `Array(1...n)`. It can be `n in(1...n).reduce...`

Comment: So an anonymous function is good enough for golf?

Comment: Of course. The same applies to a lambda in Python, and that's because it's valid even without the declaration, since you can call it like `({n in Array(1...n).reduce(0){$0+Int(String("\($1)".characters.reversed()))!}})(someValue)` anyway

Answer (score 0):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), 13 bytes

```
+/.:'|:'$1+!:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P81KW1/PSr3GSl3FUFvR6n@aup6VgVXCf0MDBVMFI0MFUwsFc1MFS0tLAA)

```
         1+!: /create list 1 2 3 ... x
        $     /turn each number into a string
     |:'      /reverse each string
  .:'         /eval each string
+/            /sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 84 bytes

Lambda from `int` to `long` (e.g. `IntToLongFunction`). Adaptation of [*coder-croc*'s solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137340).

```java
n->{long s=0;while(n>0)s+=new Long(new StringBuffer(""+n--).reverse()+"");return s;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XVDLasMwEDw7X7H4JGFbJIXSusaBtlAotJe6t9CD6siuUmVl9HAIxt/uynFOBcE@tDM7swfe80x3Ag/736nz30rWUCtuLbxziTCsos7InjsB1nEXPhuJXMEhwJh3UrHGY@2kRvaK7lO/aWxfrh0wHFvxIXphrKj8EcoJs@2gwgjYcl2cfqQSBLdrapMSxQlmMJmTyhmJ7ZNvGmFIHCeYZZSZhYjQJI5pYYTzBsEW4xQVq6BykX4V2Wu5h2MwQBaq3Rdw01o6@4kabYBIdMCfuRXwAPPKUIehYbNO4TaFm00I9ynchTzP83EBRtXZOnFk2jsWroJOIfnnkfGuU@dHe7Fy4ae0CNBxFd44/QE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 10 bytes

```
smBa"I_Va"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P@/ONcpUckzPixR6f9/QwMA)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 18 Bytes

```
+/(".@|.@":)"0>:i.
```

#### Explanation:

```
+/                 | Sum of
  (".@|.@":)       | Reverse
            "0     | Each member of
              >:i. | Integers from 1 to n inclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 89 bytes

```powershell
param($n)function q($x){(($a=$x|% t*y)|%{$a[--$i]})-join''}1..$n|%{$s+=[int](q("$_"))};$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoMwEAXQq4h8caYlUtfFk4hIKJam2ImaSBXN2af0bd/kv8MSXsM4qk52sR@C8HOVR3Respmw8UEE22A7iyxedj6LA7Y1Bq5LbN7eSVmmuqog/wnXpnUSO5opR58zpzuCqta3Hw)

Answer (score 0):

## x86, 27 bytes

```
f:	xor esi, esi	; Input ecx
	push 10
	pop ebx
.p:	mov eax, ecx
	xor edi, edi
.q:	xor edx, edx
	div ebx
	imul edi, 10
	add edi, edx
	test eax, eax
	jnz .q
	add esi, edi
	loop .p
	ret		; Output esi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/dTsQgEIWvmaeYu71wS7r@RFuvdxMTEx/B0AIRA4UtYFhfvgKLCgmEM2e@MzDvhZn0pZPMm22TdjUs4PH1hCKJOQY2aYF3AO8@sDWMQIz9QjGnPQ7DAGRmWqPMt3EovNrj/UPZQD4XgX1zs@w@ALZVpSlL/Z@kloB9esoCAMiRJLteafkgz/iyuBhKKBAX/QceMthZVyhA3fgfUi21mZdmroCeG42XMs9lrmo8EGWivhoLj3H@25VrQfjQkCyVz3wjPTeTb2iibZ6BOiCrCCSP@RZDndOrjYqFjyXLO80uWJ6d7G4fb3b9bvsB)

Seem not answered

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 52 bytes

```arturo
$[n][sum map 1..n=>[to :integer reverse to :string]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?OLn1iu)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 12 bytes

```
,{)`-1%~+}*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlf/V@nWjNB11C1TrtWS/N/rVWatZJnXkFpiYKunYJ/aQmQFZMXk6cUbWigYKpgZKhgaqFgbqpgaWkZW62XpgRSpRSjrV2rmqf1HwA)

## Explanation

```
code         # explanation           | stack
,{)`-1%~+}*) # function with input n | n
,            # range                 | [0..n)
 {       }*  # fold this block over  | [0..n)
  )          # increment             | [1..n]
   `         # stringify             | ["1"..str(n)]
    -1%      # map by -1 (reverse)   | [rev("1")..rev(str(n)]
       ~     # eval                  | [rev(1)..rev(n)]
        +    # add (effectively sum) | sum([rev(1)..rev(n)])
           ) # increment             | sum([rev(1)..rev(n)])+1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RṃN
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhZLgx7ubPZbUpyUXAwVWbDI0ADCAgA)

##### Explanation

```python
RṃN  # Implicit input        -> 10
R    # Push [1..input]       -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 ṃ   # Reverse each          -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, '01']
  N  # Cast each to int      -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
     # S flag sums the list  -> 46
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 40 bytes

Anonymous Immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` of the `activesheet` object and outputs to the Immediate Window console.

```vb
For i=1To[A1]:u=u--StrReverse(i):Next:?u
```