# Backwards Alphabet Triangle

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

Without taking any input, output this exact text:

```
                         A
                        B A
                       C B A
                      D C B A
                     E D C B A
                    F E D C B A
                   G F E D C B A
                  H G F E D C B A
                 I H G F E D C B A
                J I H G F E D C B A
               K J I H G F E D C B A
              L K J I H G F E D C B A
             M L K J I H G F E D C B A
            N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
           O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
          P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
         Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
        R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
       S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
      T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
     U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
    V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
   W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
  X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
 Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
```

### Rules

- Output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT or return it as a function result.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- A single trailing newline is acceptable, but no other formatting changes are allowed.
- Capital letters are required.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: `A single trailing newline is acceptable, but no other formatting changes are allowed.` So a trailing space on each line would not be permitted?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Correct - no trailing spaces. Darn that rules out [char][space] times length, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: Can we return a list of strings?

Comment: @NickKennedy Yes, that's fine.

Comment: I like the 3d bump effect around the J.

Comment: @NickKennedy You might be interested to know that output as a list of lines is now an accepted [default IO method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/76162)

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 53 bytes

```hs
[tail$do c<-reverse a;' ':[c|c<=d]|d<-a]
a=['A'..'Z']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxEsIgEADA3ldckZmryAMUCt9gJ1LcHKcynsgASZW3S7LVvql9RHVU9xi@U9Ip/oCtqbJKbQJ0QcCz542ti2GL1lA4kfN4xXnGO4bxpZTBQVn6rVeYYMmasrRjdfz5qfRqw3ApOw)

This uses that each line has exactly 25 spaces. So, instead of separately handling the prefix spaces and the spaces between letters, we take 26 spaces, and decide whether to put a letter after each. This unfortunately gives one extra leading space, which we remove.

---

**54 bytes**

```hs
foldl(\m c->map(' ':)m++[c:' ':last m])["A"]['B'..'Z']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZRCoMwDADQqwQZRBE9gKCwXWF/1n6ETp0sqaWt1ze69/W@lH4zs8Z@0mXnD5eTgGsGoVAiYFdJXRvX/cuUMoitTPEsrMEXti2OaFVo89BDOPI7R3jA4Xnzc7oX9XQL05q0cSFc)

---

**55 bytes**

```hs
"A"%['B'..'[']
s%(h:t)=((' '<$t)++s):(h:' ':s)%t
s%_=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoMwEEDRfU8xiGESpB4gmEV7hS5TkSBWxRhCZrx@xyz/42@BjiVGKe4rzatRHt/Y9@hxfJDSm2XjtEbAoWXTdWRstZqWjOJ6TM6PcoY9gYN88YcLtHCluKeFoMh//sWwkjznnG8)

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>82 79 77 75</s>  74 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*
*Saved 1 byte thanks to [@gastropner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75886/gastropner)*

Derived from my 2<sup>nd</sup> JS answer.

```c
f(x,y,s){for(x=0,y=25;~y;putchar(s>51?x=!y--,13:s&x>y?90-s/2:32))s=++x+y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEADAu69IL2WXJFQjHjRE3yIpqR6s4tqyi9ivpzPRvmLMOQEbMYRnWnfgUBoJrvE/8dvniNO4A/VNNXC4ibWmqju6cy9DW1p6uK52iBS0Zi3@yt91fqplnN@A6iyUSoC@uPIf)

#### How?

We start with \$x=0\$ and \$y=25\$. We increment \$x\$ at the beginning of the line. We set \$x\$ to \$0\$ and decrement \$y\$ at the end of the line, which is reached when \$x+y=52\$. We stop when \$y=-1\$.

This gives:

```
   0        1         2         3
   123456789012345678901234567890...
25 .........................A
24 ........................B.A
23 .......................C.B.A
22 ......................D.C.B.A
21 .....................E.D.C.B.A
 ⋮
```

We append a letter when \$x+y\$ is odd and \$x\$ is greater than \$y\$, or a space otherwise.

The ASCII code of the letter at \$(x,y)\$ is given by:

$$90-\left\lfloor\frac{x+y}{2}\right\rfloor, (x+y)\equiv 1 \pmod 2$$

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEADAu69IL2WXJFQjHjRE3yIpqR6sIrbsrtivpzPRvmLMOQEZNoJnWnegUBoOrvE/9tvniNO4g/RNNVC4sbWmqju5U89DW1p5uK52iBK0Js3@yt91fqplnN@A6iyUSoC@uPIf)

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>7</s> 9 bytes

```
ＵＴ↙Ｅα…α⊕κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88zyc1rURHwTexQCNRR8G5Mjkn1TkjH8zxzEsuSs1NzStJTdHI1gQC6////@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  α     Uppercase alphabet
 Ｅ      Map over characters
    α   Uppercase alphabet
   …    Truncated to length
      κ Current index
     ⊕  Incremented
↙       Output with a 135° rotation
```

Effectively, this starts with the `A` in the bottom right corner, then works its way to the top left printing longer and longer prefixes of the uppercase alphabet each time, each prefix being printed towards the bottom left. The `ＵＴ` simply suppresses Charcoal's default rectangular output, apparently needed for this question for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>16, 15</s>, 12 bytes

```
¬ZAòé hòòxâÄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//9CaKMfDmw6vVMgAkpsqDi863PL/PwA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: ac5a 41f2 e920 68f2 f278 e2c4            .ZA.. h..x..
```

Thanks to Kritixi Lithos for helping me golf a few off.

Explanation:

```
¬ZA                 " Insert every character between 'Z' and 'A'
                    " The cursor is on the 'A'
   ò         ò      " Recursively...
    é<space>        "   Insert a space
            h       "   Move back one character
                    "   If we're on the first column, this will break the loop
              ò     " Recursively...
               x    "   Delete the current character
                â   "   Stop looping if there's only one non-whitespace character on this line
                 Ä  "   Duplicate this line upward
```

Comment: Hint for 14b: you can do better than `Ó`

Comment: @KritixiLithos I'll see your 14, and raise you 12 :)

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `â` (looks like there are a few other similar ones in normal_keys.vim)

Comment: Does this count as 12 bytes though? 12 characters, yes. Same goes for the answer of Neil: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194860/90048

Comment: @D.Kovács Yes, it is exactly 12 bytes. See the hexdump I provided

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + common GNU tools, 42

```bash
echo {Z..A}|sed -n ':l;p;s/[B-Z]//;tl'|tac
```

#### Explanation

- `echo {Z..A}` is a bash brace expansion that outputs `Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A`
- The sed expression is a loop that:

  - `:l`  Define a label l
  - `p`rint the current pattern space
  - `s/[B-Z]//` match the first instance of B-Z and replace it with ""
  - `tl` if a match occurred above, jump back to label l
  - (implicit) otherwise quit.  `-n` suppresses implicit output of the pattern space at the end of line processing.
- The output of the sed is the required triangle, but upside down.  The `tac` reverses it line-by-line to give the required output.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@hOkpPz7G2pjg1RUE3T0HdKse6wLpYP9pJNypWX9@6JEe9piQx@f9/AA)

Comment: -1:

echo {Z..A}|sed ':l;/[B-Z]/p;s///;tl'|tac

Comment: @jnfnt Thanks.  I see that it does work, but so far I haven't been able to figure out how.  In particular the `s///` appears to be deleting the first B-Z letter in the pattern space - but how does that work?

Comment: If the pattern between the first two slashes after "s" is empty, sed will assume you want to use the previous regular expression that was used. 

(From https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html:

"The empty regular expression ‘//’ repeats the last regular expression match")

Answer (score 5):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html), 686 bytes

```
the a-b-c corner
i was a child of ten or eleven
i said i am smart,i am likely to get an answer
i got a chance to read papers,novels or some old poetry
i read in class
as i read,i paused a bit
the words,i do admit,were a huge issue
please tutor,i said,i desire a nap
i truly do not
i fibbed
i am hiding a r-real g-great l-lie,a secret
i am idiot,i cant t-truly r-r-read
i think im reading,really im no smart reader
i need a lesson,i say,i really do
not a whole lot of people are helping teach me
i want a tutor,i say,i really want someone smart
i call a skilled tutor on my phone
as i call a person,i see a letter key,then i press down
it worked!i see a letter shape
amazing start for me
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?XVLRrp0wDHvnK7J3@KjQ5tCK0qAmDLGfv3PL1TZNQmrVOI4d40mIl3UJFLRVaVOmm42YQsolkn7Ib51yJQtJtVAm4xxx8EF2cPNpXEvepTzkSps4ccVn92Db1Acb1yC93oQjnXxKs7nqTylG2sj0EFIMPFW8PegbOMwNhc0mSHqf5ozmyySCdM0@OfTf2qKhEJU4HtlnTIYrStcmlM0umc4ibJh/ubb59dAbxPJAVj4x0tsFD2Cp2m198rpKfP2lHHPdgGwLVBTalg2nU1lKlpnJJDT53gWg6mAPXJ18eVnR1zs7nadcd8rH8APWuTMCgpeq71JHaayvyrBaxEzrUP7MYxNlSJ3qWO@dtAgV3BHYKQq7xHCWpJxdtwuHRIeMdGvv@LuJf/hGrUehVf6kG1BCg@25FGgZjaSVjofOBOCbzTeqx/rqFBmy3aXRLs@MoCpwZ4MTCL/rlL0nt0v88R/cEn6PiQ/@1bWb94V8MPSQr6@V428)

Poetic is an esolang I made in 2018 for a class project. It's basically brainfuck with word-lengths instead of symbols.

Comment: Woah neat language!

Comment: I like how typos of missing spaces are intentional

Comment: The spaces are missing only because I'm golfing this language. Usually, programmers of Poetic are encouraged to use spacing and punctuation freely (and use words more than 10 letters long for those pesky runs of small numbers ;) ).

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 34 bytes

```
((32#~26-#)<@u:@,32,@,.65+|.)\i.26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BS8NAFITv@ysGC9rQdCkp5hCsRAUPUjyI4MXLZvu2uxLeSvZFFMS/Hrehpwcz37yZj8lhpy80Nmg2WGs8vOwfp@VyWy3@qnq9KG7asWnLbVW2pa6vV7@6eA@6qqdCPd9rvHqC6eIXYSAZB04wcCNbCZGzlMZeGszkHfqQBNGhi9@UQMZ62MhiAgc@5tzJn9E3AhMdzmBgPKEja8ZEkNzXB86yN7n0EJyjgVjQEx/FJzU/2JNcJXzmSfKTT8j@KXjeoxRZHy9v4dT0Dw)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 37 bytes

```powershell
25..0|%{' '*$_+[char[]]((90-$_)..65)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/38hUT8@gRrVaXUFdSyVeOzo5I7EoOjZWQ8PSQFclXlNPz8xUs/b/fwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>78 72</strike> 63 bytes

```r
for(i in 1:26){cat(strrep(" ",26-i));cat(LETTERS[i:1],fill=52)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdDKyEyzOjmxRKO4pKgotUBDSUFJx8hMN1NT0xok6uMaEuIaFBydaWUYq5OWmZNja2qkWfv/PwA)

Nothing fancy. First print spaces, then print letters.

Improvement inspired by https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195078/89953, but cannot comment there because of reputation.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
i=26
s='A'
while i:i-=1;print' '*i+s;s='%c '%(91-i)+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWyIyr2FbdUZ2rPCMzJ1Uh0ypT19bQuqAoM69EXUFdK1O72Boor5qsoK6qYWmom6mpXfz/PwA)

We take care not to introduce any trailing spaces, which means avoiding `center` and also avoiding adding a space with `A` for the first row.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>57</s> 54 bytes

```ruby
?A.upto(?Z){puts' '*(90-_1.ord)+[*?A.._1].reverse*' '}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN83sHfVKC0ryNeyjNKsLSkuK1RXUtTQsDXTjDfXyi1I0taO1gCr04g1j9YpSy1KLilO1gCpqIbqhhsAMAwA)

Comment: You can save one byte by moving `puts` inside `(?A..?Z).map{|c|puts' '*(90-c.ord)+[*?A..c].reverse*' '}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>76</strike> 75 bytes:

-1 byte thanks to [@pppery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46076/pppery)

```
for i in range(27):print((27-i)*' '+' '.join(chr(64+i-x)for x in range(i)))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8hc06qgKDOvRAPI1M3U1FJXUNcGYr2s/Mw8jeSMIg0zE@1M3QpNkL4KhL5MTU3N//8B).

Another **75 bytes**:

```
for i in range(27):print(' '.join(chr(64+i-x)for x in range(i)).center(51))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Rco7CoAwDADQq2RrgljwD95GSrVxSEvoUE8fcfLNrzw1ZZnMzqzAwAJ6yBVx3GgvylLRgfN3ZsGQFNe5477Rl9ufmciHKDUqLgOR2Qs).

Comment: You can remove the space in `chr(65+x) for x in ...`.

Comment: @pppery it have been fixed. tnx.

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｚ［± ＊ＺＬ³－ ××］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNCJUIxJTIwJXVGRjBBJXVGRjNBJXVGRjJDJUIzJXVGRjBEJTIwJUQ3JUQ3JXVGRjNE,v=8)

Explanation:

```
Z[± *ZL³- ××]
Z[          ] map over the prefixes of the uppercase alphabet
  ±             reverse the current prefix
    *           interleave it with spaces
     ZL³-       substract the loop index from 26
          ×     that many spaces
           ×    prepend the spaces to the prefix
```

[7 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNCJUIxJTIwJXVGRjBBJXVGRjNEJXVGRjBG,v=8) with padding with spaces. yep, 2x bytecount to "remove" them..

Comment: [Alternate 7 byter with space padding](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNCJTIwJXVGRjBBJXUyMTk0JXVGRjNEJXVGRjUy,v=8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 76 bytes

```
Array[StringRiffle[Reverse@ToUpperCase@Alphabet[][[;;#]]]&,26]~Column~Center
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answer meets the specifications of the challenge as written, since the correct output includes literal rows of spaces. The shortest compliant version I can come up with is 83 bytes (including a golf of the row generation): `StringRiffle[PadLeft[Capitalize@Alphabet[][[#;;1;;-1]]&~Array~26]/. 0->"","~"," "]&`, replacing the `~` with a literal newline. Note that the space in `/. 0` is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ØALḶ⁶ẋṚżUK$ƤY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//w5hBTOG4tuKBtuG6i@G5msW8VUskxqRZ//8)

A full program that prints the desired output to STDOUT.

### Explanation

```
ØA            | Uppercase letters
  L           | Length (26)
   Ḷ          | Lowered range (0..25)
    ⁶ẋ        | Space that many times (vectorises)
      Ṛ       | Reverse list
       ż      | Zip with:
          $Ƥ  | - Following applied to each prefix of the uppercase letters:
        U     |   - Reverse
         K    |   - Join with spaces
            Y | Join with newlines
```

Without the final Y, a list of lists of Jelly strings woulf be returned, with the spaces and letters in separate sublists. As such, I’ve gone with joining the outer list with newlines and relying on Jelly’s default printing method to produce the correct output.

Comment: As outputting a list of lines is acceptable, you can remove the `Y`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The issue is that the output would be a list of lists of strings because of the `ż`, and it’s only by virtue of Jelly’s outputting to STDOUT that it looks ok.

Comment: As strings are the same as char arrays (which are generated by your program) in Jelly, I'd argue that the output constitutes a list of lines. However, it's entirely up to you whether to accept that argument or not.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The issue is it doesn’t return a list of character arrays, but a list of lists of two character arrays each - the spaces and letters are in separate sub lists. I’ve previously been told by more experienced golfers that such a return type wouldn’t be permitted, and so I’ve gone with the output to STDOUT. Replacing `ż` with `;"` would resolve the issue, but I’d then still be at 13 bytes without the `Y`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>57</s> <s>52</s> 42 bytes

```
T`L`_L
}`^
Z
.
$.`$* $&$'¶
\B\w
 $&
O`
G`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JMEnId6HqzYhjiuKS49LRS9BRUtBRU1F/dA2rhinmHIuIIfLP4HLPUHv/38A) Explanation:

```
T`L`_L
```

Move all of the letters so far one step backwards in the alphabet, but delete any `A`.

```
^
Z
```

Prefix a `Z` to the current string.

```
}`
```

Repeat the above until the transformation becomes idempotent. This happens when the string is the entire alphabet; the `A` is deleted, the `Z-B` get transliterated into `Y-A`, and another `Z` is prefixed.

```
.
$.`$* $&$'¶
```

Turn the alphabet into a triangle.

```
\B\w
 $&
```

Space out the letters.

```
O`
```

Get the lines in the correct order.

```
G`.
```

Remove an extraneous trailing newline. (Retina 0.8.2 always adds a trailing newline, so there would have been two; had I used Retina 1 I could have claimed that newline as my allowed newline.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;Båi ®¬¸Ãû
mx1
```

Saved a byte thanks to @Shaggy.

Gained 4 bytes due to fixing a bug.

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0LlaSCurLjD%2bwpteDE)

Comment: `rPS` can be `¬¸`.

Comment: @dzaima Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>34</s> 33  bytes

-1 byte thanks to ngn

```
(-26-!26)$`c${,/32,'|65+!x}'1+!26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0PXyExX0chMUyUhWaVaR9/YSEe9xsxUW7GiVt1QGyjx/z8A)

Comment: `\`c$'` -> `\`c$`

Comment: @ngn Thank you! I should have tried it myself :)

Comment: ah, i missed this submission. mine is an awful lot like this but in k4 ...

Comment: @scrawl Your solution is much shorter them mine :)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 27 bytes

```
1_|^\(," "/+,a),a:`c$90-!26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/98wviYuRkNHSUFJX1snUVMn0SohWcXSQFfRyOz/fwA)

`!26` is `0 1`..`25`

`90-!26` is `90 89`..`65`

`` `c$ `` convert to chars: `"ZY`..`A"`

`a:` assign to `a`

`(,`..`),` prepend as a single element

- `+,a` flip enlist, i.e. make each char a length-1 string: `(,"Z";,"Y";`..`;,"A")`
- `" "/` join with spaces (in some dialects of k this may be `" "/:`)

`^\` without-scan, i.e. start with `"Z Y`..`A"`, then remove `"Z"`, then remove `"Y"`, etc, and collect intermediate results

`|` reverse

`1_` drop the first, as it's an all-spaces string

Comment: This outputs with parens and quotes. I don't think that's allowed.

Comment: @pppery "You can print it to STDOUT _or return it as a function result_."

Comment: Sorry, not very familiar with the K language, and the fact that this does produce output when run as a full program confused me.

Comment: @pppery no worries. k tries to print objects in such a way that feeding the output back into the interpreter produces an equivalent object. in this case `(` `)` is a `\n`-separated list (or equivalently, it could be `;`-separated) of `"`strings`"`.

Comment: @pppery many languages print the result of a line by default. this is especially common among golfing languages, but also present in some practical languages like apl and its family, which k is a member of.

Comment: What dialect of K would you suggest for learning the language?

Comment: @Jonah my favourite is k5/k6 (these were very similar, so i consider them a single dialect), which is what oK and ngn/k follow. oK has a [nice manual](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/blob/gh-pages/docs/Manual.md) and [interactive examples](https://johnearnest.github.io/ok/ike/ike.html). unfortunately the real k5 and k6 never saw the light of day.

Comment: Thanks for the links @ngn

Comment: @Jonah if you intend to get a job - k4 is still widely used in the form of kdb+ and q, so it might be worth learning. there are some learning materials about it at kx systems' website. 32-bit k4 is free for non-commercial use. [kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona) follows the older k3. the newest "[shakti](https://shakti.com/)", also known as k7, is still being designed; it might change significantly before it's released. it's followed by [ktye/i](https://github.com/ktye/i).

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 82 bytes

```java
v->{var x="";for(char c=64;++c<91;)System.out.printf("%"+(c-38)+"s%n",x=c+" "+x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU1Na8MgGL73V7wIBcVFKBtjw6aXnXcq7DJ6cG9jZ2Y06GtIKfntme3p4fnuzWSa/vy3ojc5w6dxAW4bgLH8eIeQyVCFKbozDNXjR0ouXL5PYNIli0cUoK8jqpDzypaA5GJQHzHkMnRp/1WrB7DtOjWH22QSzC1j2sbE8bcybF9ftJS4f99pcbxm6gYVC6mx3pDlbMskx@b5TUiWt4E9zS1KBkzOQi@rfrxbZRC7kXgo3ou7tmyW9R8)

### Credits

- -2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##HU1Na8MgGL73V7wIBcVFKBtjw6aXnXcq7DJ6cG9jZ2Y06GtIKfntme3p4fnuzWSa/vy3ojc5w6dxAW4bgLH8eIeQyVCFKbozDNXjR0ouXL5PYNIli0cUoK8jqpDzypaA5GJQHzHkMnRp/1WrB7DtOjWH22QSzC1j2sbE8bcybF9ftJS4f99pcbxm6gYVC6mx3pDlbMskx@b5TUiWt4E9zS1KBkzOQi@rfrxbZRC7kXgo3ou7tmyW9R8)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ASuηí».c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fMbj03PbDaw/t1kv@/x8A)

```
A           # push the alphabet, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 S          # split to a list of chars
  u         # uppercase
   η        # prefixes
    í       # reverse each
     »      # join by newlines, joining sublists by spaces
      .c    # center
```

Comment: Here is an alternative [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L6CYL3iQ7v1kv//BwA "05AB1E – Try It Online") solution. Same idea and same bytecount, but uses fewer commands.

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 62 bytes

```forth
: f 25 for i spaces 25 i - for i 65 + emit ."  "next cr next ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRiZKgB5CpkKxQWJyanFIH6mgi5UzMxUQVshNTezREFPSUFBKS@1okQhuUgBTFv/T/sPAA)

#### Code explanation

```forth
: f            \ start a new word definition
  25 for       \ loop from 25 to 0
    i spaces   \ print loop-index spaces
    25 i - for \ loop from (25 - loop-index) to 0
      i 65 +   \ add inner loop-index to 65 (ascii 'A')
      emit     \ output ascii char for value
      ."  "    \ output a single space
    next       \ end inner loop
    cr         \ output a newline
  next         \ end outer loop
;              \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## k4, 24 bytes

```
(-26-!26)$|:',\.Q.A,'" "
```

explanation:

```
               .Q.A,'" " /append space to each capital letter ("A ";"B "; "C "; ... )
             ,\          /join scan, join each element successively and return intermediate results ("A ";"A B ";"A B C "; ... )
          |:'            /reverse each
(-26-!26)$               /left-pad each with -26 -27 -28 ...
```

run like:

```
q)k)(-26-!26)$|:',\.Q.A,'" "
"                         A"
"                        B A"
"                       C B A"
"                      D C B A"
..
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 35 bytes

```
25* 

.
Y`.`RL
L^$w`^(..)*
$#1* $'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vIVEuBi0uPKzJBLyHIh8snTqU8IU5DT09Ti0tF2VBLQUX9/38A) Explanation:

```
25*
```

Insert 25 spaces.

```
.
```

Insert `.`s in all available positions. This results in 26 `.`s, because both the start and end can have a `.` inserted.

```
Y`.`RL
```

Cyclically transliterate the `.`s using a reversed uppercase alphabet.

```
L^$w`^(..)*
```

List all (necessarily overlapping) prefixes of even numbers of characters, in reverse order (i.e. longest prefix to shortest).

```
$#1* $'
```

For each prefix, output the number of pairs as a run of spaces (effectively deleting the letters) plus its suffix.

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>103</s> <s>93</s> 77 bytes

```
N	&UCASE B LEN(1) . B @X :F(END)
	A =B ' ' A
	OUTPUT =LPAD(A,26 + X) :(N)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/349TLdTZMdhVwUnBx9VPw1BTQQ/IdIhQsHLTcPVz0eTidFSwdVJQB0JHLk7/0JCA0BAFW58ARxcNRx0jMwVthQhNBSsNP00uoOr//wE)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 79 bytes

```
=LET(k,ROW(1:26),REPT(" ",26-k)&RIGHT(CONCAT(" "&CHAR(91-TRANSPOSE(k))),2*k-1))
```

Explanation

```
k,ROW                                                         ' k = 1..26
REPT(" ",26-k)&RIGHT(CONCAT(" "&CHAR(91-TRANSPOSE(k))),2*k-1) ' Final Calculation
REPT(" ",26-k)                                                ' 26-k spaces
                     CONCAT(" "&CHAR(91-TRANSPOSE(k)))        ' " Z Y ...
               RIGHT(                                 ,2*k-1) ' Right 2k-1 characters
```

Answer (score 2):

## vim, <strike>42</strike> 41 bytes

```
:set nf=alpha
aZ<ESC>qqYp<C-x>q24@qVggJqqYPxq24@q
```

`<ESC>` is 0x1b, `<C-x>` is 0x18, `<NL>` is 0x0a.

### Annotated

```
:set nf=alpha   # make <C-x> work with letters
aZ<ESC>         # put Z in buffer
qqYp<C-x>q      # Record macro q: Append a line with the previous letter
24@q            # ...and execute until we have all the letters
VggJ            # combine all lines into "Z Y X ... C B A"
qqYPxq         # Record macro q: Copy line to previous line, delete first char
24@q            # ...and execute until we have all the rows
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36o4tUQhL802MacgI5ErMUq6sDCyQKLQyMShMCw93QvIC6gA8/7/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), <s>256</s> 240 bytes

-16 thanks to @Lyxal because I can't read! XD

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/514086333)

At first, I thought it would be shorter to add each string manually, but I was very wrong! It doesn't look very good outside of monospace fonts though...

```
delete all of[P v
set[A v]to[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
set[C v]to(25
set[L v]to( 
repeat(26
set[S v]to(
repeat(C
set[S v]to(join(S)( 
change[C v]by(-1
set[L v]to(join(join(letter(round((length of(L))/(2)))of(A))( ))(L
add(join(S)(L))to[P v
```

Comment: Hey so just a heads up - consider submitting a function instead of a full program, as `define` is shorter than `when gf clicked`, and it removes the need for the painful length of `ask()and wait`

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>65</s>  63 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @l4m2*

```javascript
f=(n=26,s=`A
`)=>n--?''.padEnd(n)+s+f(n,Buffer([91-n,32])+s):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjz9bITKfYNsGRK0HT1i5PV9deXV2vIDHFNS9FI09Tu1g7TSNPx6k0LS21SCPa0lA3T8fYKBYormmlrv4/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTUNT8z8A)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 79 bytes

More maths, more bytes.

```javascript
f=(x=y=0)=>y<26?Buffer([x<y+26?y+x++&x>25-y?156-x+y>>1:32:(x=!++y,13)])+f(x):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvBDoIwDADQb/EibeqMG4HDwkbibxgPBFejIYyAmvbrJ8d3eO/hN2zj@lo@Zs6PVAoHkKDhgiFq59r@@mVOK9ykU9qpJERHia4x2tumNUIao/W18/s7EOnJ1nhHYhD0VVXGPG95SucpP4EBsfwB)

Comment: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjz9bITKfYNsGRK0HT1i5PV9deXV2vIDHFNS9FI09Tu1g7TSNPx6k0LS21SCPa0lA3T8fYKBYormmlrv4/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTUNT8z8A

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>46</s> 43 bytes

***-3 bytes** from @pxeger using `eval` instead of a for loop*

```sh
eval a={A..Z}'\ $a;echo ${(l:26+i++:)a%?};'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKgW/E/tSwxRyHRttpRTy@qVj1GQSXROjU5I19BpVojx8rITDtTW9tKM1HVvtZa/f9/AA)

The `eval` expands to:

```sh
a=A\ $a;echo ${(l:26+i++:)a%?}; a=B\ $a;echo ${(l:26+i++:)a%?}; ...
```

Which is the same as the for loop from the second 46-byte solution below:

---

**Originals:**

```sh
for c ({A..Z})a=($c $a)&&echo ${(l:25-i++:)}$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVlBo9pRTy@qVjPRVkMlWUElUVNNLTU5I19BpVojx8rIVDdTW9tKs1Yl8f9/AA)

Abuses arrays implicitly joining on spaces. `l:expr:` pads on the `l`eft with spaces until at `expr` characters wide. Putting parameter expansion flags with no parameter like this causes them to operate on an empty string.

---

Alternate **46 byte** solution, using a string with `${a%postfixremoval}` instead. Note that here we increment the padding width to accommodate the growing total string length.

```sh
for c ({A..Z})a=$c\ $a&&echo ${(l:26+i++:)a%?}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVlBo9pRTy@qVjPRViU5RkElUU0tNTkjX0GlWiPHyshMO1Nb20ozUdW@9v9/AA)

Comment: 43: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/tSwxRyHRttpRTy@qVj1GQSXROjU5I19BpVojx8rITDtTW9tKM1HVvtZa/f9/AA "Zsh – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 91 bytes

```
for _ in range(26):print(f'{" ".join([*map(chr,range(65,91))][0:_+1][::-1]):^52}'.rstrip())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFeITNPoSgxLz1Vw8hM06qgKDOvRCNNvVpJQUkvKz8zTyNaKzexQCM5o0gHosrMVMfSUFMzNtrAKl7bMDbaykrXMFbTKs7UqFZdr6i4pCizQENT8/9/AA)

*-1 byte thanks to @cairdcoinheringaahing*

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just as a start, there are a few quick golfs that you can do, such as removing the space after the colon. I'd recommend linking to an online testing environment, such as [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctNCoAgEEDhq7hzBAssKpqrRIVEP0aNYm4iOrsJLT94z91hs1TGuFjPRmaIeU3rDEoWjUDnDQXgDw5V8fI8NadOZjzfrSE4zBXg1A6mzcv/qyvZKiFEh2PfIWaqT4jxAw "Python 3 – Try It Online"), so that others can verify and help you golf your solution

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thank you! Nice tips ;) and you just saved me one byte!

Comment: Your output has trailing spaces from the centering, which this challenge does not allow.

Comment: @xnor Nice catch! Fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
VlGp*dt-lGNjdr_<GhN1
```

Pretty happy with this, since it's my first Pyth answer. Probably can be golfed a lot

## Explanation

```
VlG   for N in range(26)

p*dt-lGN    26-N spaces outputted


    <GhN   First N alphabet characters
   _       Reversed
  r        Capitalised
j       1  Joined with spaces (space after each character)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyzHvUArpUQ3x90vK6Uo3sY9w8/w/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 76 bytes

```
a:""repeat n 26[insert a rejoin[sp#"@"+ n]print next pad/left copy a n + 26]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxCoAwDADAr4Q4dhAcHJx8g2vpEGyEiqQhzaCvr93vjHM/OMfUaUM0ViYHgWWNRRqbA4HxXYvEphPuGECSWpGB@HVQyvPDl8NZ9RtWIIybev8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 84 bytes

```
procedure main()
s:="";i:=1to 26&s[1:1]:=" "||char(64+i)&write(right(s,25+i))&\z
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSE3MTNPQ5Or2MpWSck608rWsCRfwchMrTja0MowFiiooFRTk5yRWKRhZqKdqalWXpRZkqpRlJmeUaJRrGNkChTTVIup4krNS/n/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

```
for i in range(26):print(' '*(25-i)+' '.join(chr(65+i-j) for j in range(i+1)))
```

A straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 33 bytes

```perl6
{(' 'Xx(25...0))Z~[\R,] 'A'..'Z'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1pDXUE9okLDyFRPT89AUzOqLjomSCdWQd1RXU9PPUq99r9ecWKlQlp@kUKa9X8A)

Anonymous code block that returns a list of lines.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                               }  # Anonymous code block
  ' 'Xx                            # String multiply spaces
       (25...0)                       # by the range 25 to 0
 (             )Z~                 # Zip these indents with
                  [\  ]               # The triangular reduced
                    R,                # Reversed list concatenation
                        'A'..'Z'      # Of the alphabet
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> <s>24</s> 25 bytes (SBCS)

```
A(\≤|:Z$- ⅍*,:Aɧ∑, ,)⑨
,)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUSPmUeeSGqsoFV2FR629WjpWjieXP@qYqKOgo/lo4gouHc3//wE)

Hey, Keg's coming 9th (at the time of writing)!
Contains unprintable characters. Uses the 26 byte approach but uses a space converted to a string to pad lines.

### Answer History

#### 25 bytes

```
A(|:Aɧ ⅍!3--*,∑, ,)1+
,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUUOqxsrx5HKFR629UorGurpaOo86Juoo6GgaanPp/P8PAA)

#### 26 bytes (SBCS)

```
A(|:Aɧ(!;;-| ,)∑, ,)1+
,
```

-4 bytes by using stack mechanics rather than the register

**Explained**

```
A(␚|:Aɧ(␚!;;-| ,)∑, ,)1+¶,
A                           #Push "A" onto the stack
(␚|                         #26 times:
    :Aɧ                     #   Push a generated range from A to the top of stack
    (␚!;;-| ,)              #   Space-align the row
    ∑, ,)                   #   Print each character space seperated
    1+                      #   Increment the top letter by one
    ¶,                      #   Print a newline
```

Substitute `␚` for the actual unprintable control key and `¶` for a literal newline

#### 30 bytes (SBCS)

```
A&(|A&:&ɧ(!;-| ,)(, ,)&1+&
,
```

**Explained**

```
A&(␚|A&:&ɧ(␚!;-| ,)(, ,)&1+&¶,
A&                              #Put A in the register
  (␚|                           #26 times:
      A&:&ɧ                     #   Push a generated range from A to the top of stack
           (␚!;-| ,)            #   Space-align the row
                    (, ,)       #   Print each character space seperated
                         &1+&   #   Increment the top letter by one
                             ¶, #   Print a newline
```

Substitute `␚` for the actual unprintable control key and `¶` for a literal newline

#### 31 bytes (SBCS)

```
A&(\≤|A&:&ɧ(\≤!-| ,)(, ,)&1+&
,
```

**Explained**

```
A&(\≤|A&:&ɧ(\≤!-| ,)(, ,)&1+&¶,)
A&                              #Store A in the register
  (\≤|                          #26 times:
      A&:&ɧ                     #   Push a generated range from A to the top
           (\≤!-| ,)            #   Align it using spaces               
                    (, ,)       #   Print the row
                         &1+&   #   Increment the letter
                             ¶,)#   Print a newline (replace ¶ w/ \n)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 81 bytes

```cs
var x="A";for(char y='\x41';++y<92;x=y+" "+x){WriteLine(new string(' ',91-y)+x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F@Wn5mikKahWf2/LLFIocJWyVHJOi2/SCM5A8ittFWPqTAxVLfW1q60sTSyrrCt1FZSUNKu0KwOL8osSfXJzEvVyEstVyguKcrMS9dQV1DXsTTUrdQEqrCu/V/LBTTYmus/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 65 bytes

```r
for(i in 1:26){cat(strrep(" ",26-i));cat(LETTERS[i:1]);cat("\n")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdDKyEyzOjmxRKO4pKgotUBDSUFJx8hMN1NT0xok6uMaEuIaFBydaWUYCxFRislT0qz9/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 31 bytes

```
(|.@;:inv,~' '#~26-#)\u:65+i.26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfpmCrp6SnYKBgZaCgq6fgHOTj9l@jRs/B2iozr0ynTl1BXbnOyExXWTOm1MrMVDtTz8jsvyZXanJGvkLafwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 51 bytes

```julia
[' '^i*join(('Z'-i:-1:'B').*' ')*'A' for i=25:-1:0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xCsIwGAZ3n@IDhz8JbbGCS8FBwUERFXFSFISk8peQSJKCPn1sXe8OrustP@tPnuJgjDYa3tkvWh9w2R4LsMNuLHDenPYFLMcE3yKmwO4VwRHBpD44oyfvASXrKpFvBHqw6jw7IehKJTdl3dCaZKUGJRWt6L/g5Xwxqtk9y/wD)

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPivrOCXmpqSmqKQn5dTqZCWX6QQ4umvo5CZp@AFUqEQ5Brgo6OQk1lcopCfplBcUpSZl16skFmsUJRaUlqUl5rCVQAUKsnJ09P4H62uoB6XqZWVn5mnoR6lrptppWtope6orgMU1wSbnWlrZAoSNIj9r/kfAA "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 22 bytes

```apl
(⌽0,⍳25)⌽⌽↑{∊⍺' '⍵}\⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X@NRz14DnUe9m41MNYFMEGqbWP2oo@tR7y51BfVHvVtrYx71TXX8/x8A)

Output of above function.

Explanation:

- `⎕A` is the uppercase alphabet character vector.
- `{∊⍺' '⍵}` is a 1 character shorter version of `{⍺,' ',⍵}` which puts a space between arguments `⍺` and `⍵`.
- Reducing `/` this function over `⎕A` would result in the uppercase alphabet with spaces between, `'A B C ...'`. Scanning `\` instead produces a nested vector of all the intermediate results, `('A') ('A B') ('A B C')...`.
- Mix `↑` turns the nested vector into a matrix, padding rows to equal length with spaces, which is then horizontally mirrored with `⌽` (the one on the right).
- To get the final answer we need to rotate the rows (dyadic `⌽`) by 25, 24, 23, ... 0 characters.
- The left argument to the rotation is the sequence 25, 24, 23, ... 0, which is obtained concisely by `⌽0,⍳25`.

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 144 bytes

Abuses token delimiters (`[` and `;`)

```
@!! 2>nul||cmd/q/v/c%0&&exit/b
set;=for /l %%A in (65 1 90)do set[=
%;% ![!
%;%![:~,-1!&cmd/cexit %%A&set]=!=exitcodeascii! !]!&echo(![!!]:~,-1!
```

---

Sources

> - [Golfing Delayed Expansion Variables in Batch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54228/golfing-delayed-expansion-variables-in-batch)
> - [`CMD.EXE` parsing - Token Delimiters](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8355&start=30)
> - [Write HEX values to file in Windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826309/12861751)

Answer (score 1):

## Deadfish~, 10394 bytes

```
{i}{i}{i}ii{c}{c}ccccc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}{c}cccc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}{c}ccc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}{c}cc{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}{c}c{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}{c}{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}ccccccccc{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}cccccccc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}ccccccc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}cccccc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}ccccc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}cccc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}ccc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}cc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}c{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}ii{c}{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iiccccccccc{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iicccccccc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iiccccccc{{i}ddddd}ic{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iicccccc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}ic{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iiccccc{{i}ddddd}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}ic{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iicccc{{i}ddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddc{{i}ddddd}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}ic{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iiccc{{i}ddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddc{{i}ddddd}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}ic{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iicc{{i}ddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddc{{i}ddddd}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}ic{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iic{{i}dddd}dddc{{d}iiii}iiic{{i}ddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddc{{i}ddddd}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}ic{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{{i}dd}c{{d}iiii}iic{{i}dddd}dddc{{d}iiii}iiic{{i}ddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiii}dddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiii}ddddc{{i}ddddd}iiic{{d}iiiii}dddc{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}ic{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}c{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}dc{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}ddc{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}dddc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiic{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}ic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}c{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}dc{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}ddc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}dddc{{d}iiiiii}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiic{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiic
```

Compared to others,  terrible!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 52 bytes

```r
write(intToUtf8(outer(26:1,1:26,"<=")*90:65,T),1,26)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVIzOvJCQ/tCTNQiO/tCS1SMPIzMpQx9DKyExHycZWSVPL0sDKzFQnRFPHUMfITPP/fwA)

A different and (for now) golfier approach than [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195078/67312) or [that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195004/67312) R answers.

To generate "exact text" as is required in [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenges, there are usually two options in R: `cat` and `write`. `cat` is more flexible, as `write` is actually a [wrapper around `cat`](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyT1/38A), but the advantage of `write` is that if you can construct your data in a rectangular (matrix) form, some of the verbosity of `cat` goes away, for instance, you get a newline without explicitly including it as you do in `cat`, which will then include an extra `sep`arator argument, which is usually undesirable. Since each line of the text here appears to be of variable width, `write` is not the first thing that comes to mind, and both of the other R answers are quite creative in getting around the shortcomings of `cat`. In particular, the `fill` argument is not one I'm familiar with, but will have to keep trying out.

The trick here is that `write`, like `cat`, separates elements by spaces. Since every line has the same number of spaces, if we can construct the right matrix of empty strings `""` and capital letters, we can just use `write` to automatically put the spaces where they go.

My first attempt started by constructing the matrix directly:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 63 bytes

```r
m=matrix(LETTERS,26,26);m[lower.tri(m)]="";write(m[26:1,],1,26)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9c2N7GkKLNCw8c1JMQ1KFjHyAyINK1zo3Pyy1OL9IByGrmasbZKStblRZklqRq50UZmVoY6sTqGIHX//wMA)

This builds up a matrix of capital letters, then sets the lower triangle to empty strings, and finally flips vertically since `write` proceeds down the columns.

This is equally as long as Bart-Jan van Rossum's answer; I was going to post it since the approach was different, but when I went to read a comment on [another completely unrelated challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137056/67312), I thought to try `intToUtf8` instead.

Two things make this possible. Typically, `intToUtf8` takes a vector of integers and converts them to a single string made up of their utf8 codepoints. There is also an optional argument, usually `FALSE` that when set to `TRUE` will instead return a vector of characters of the utf8 codepoints. The other trick is that `intToUtf8(0)` returns the empty string. So instead of constructing a matrix of `""` and `LETTERS`, I constructed a matrix of codepoints, which ended up (finally) being shorter than the other R answers:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 61 bytes

```r
write(intToUtf8((outer(1:26,1:26,"<=")*65:90)[26:1,],T),1,26)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVIzOvJCQ/tCTNQkMjv7QktUjD0MrITAdMKNnYKmlqmZlaWRpoRhuZWRnqxOqEaOoY6hiZaf7/DwA)

Luckily, despite `intToUtf8` returning a `vector`, `write` takes a `ncolumns` argument to specify how many columns wide it ought to be, which provides enough structure for `write` to print it correctly.

Finally, there are a couple of inefficient golfs which bring it to its current 52 byte form.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 10 bytes

```
kA¦RvṄøĊøR
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwia0HCplJ24bmEw7jEisO4UiIsIiIsIiJd)

Very nice

### Explained (old)

```
₄ƛkAẎṘṄ
₄ƛ        # over the range [1, 26]: (call each item n)
  kAẎ     #     push "ABCDE....XYZ"[0:n]
     ṘṄ   #     reverse and join on spaces
          # the -C flag auto-centers the top of the stack
```

Comment: [6 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=C&code=kA%C2%A6%C6%9B%E1%B9%98%E1%B9%84&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [OP has said no trailing spaces are allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194846/backwards-alphabet-triangle/223299#comment463827_194846)

Comment: [Does this work for 7?](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJDIiwiIiwia0HCpnbhuZh24bmEIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 189 bytes

`++[[+<]>+>++]<->>+[+[<]>>+<+]>>>-[-[-<]>>+<]>-<++++++++++<<<<<<<<[-[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]>[->>>>>>>.<<<<<<<]>>[->+>+<<]<+[->>>+<<<<+<+>>]<[->>>>-.>>>.<<<<<<<]<[->>+<<]>>>>>[-]<[-<+>]>>>.<<<<<<<<]`

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##TY1RCsRACEMPFOwJQi4ifmwLhbKwHwt7/qk6pd0IDpoXZ/2@js/@295jAO5gCAKCJsHhOQtEdplnzTlkxC1eKr/STD9JqB5NLReT8Rsi2u58/iEFJ2/Lf6KXfbTkVos@/jCMMU4)

(Using 8-bit wrapping)

I cannot put into words how much I hate this language.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
L26_⁶x;KU$
ØAÇƤY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/HyCz@UeO2CmvvUBWuwzMcD7cfWxL5/z8A)

This seems too long for Jelly, despite being terrible at [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) challenges

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 63 bytes

```
[(' '<$[c..'Y'])++foldl(\s->(:' ':s))"A"['B'..c]|c<-['A'..'Z']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzP1pDXUHdRiU6WU9PPVI9VlNbOy0/JyVHI6ZY107DCihnVaypqeSoFK3upK6nlxxbk2yjG63uCGSrR6nHxv7PTczMU7BVyE0s8I1XKCgtCS4p8slTSPv/LzktJzG9@L9uckEBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 29 bytes

```
;1o27@Bt0X)w)ò1)qS)ùS25+X})qR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/39ow38jcwanEIEKzXPPwJkPNwmDNwzuDjUy1I2o1C4P@/wcA)

Comment: This can be done in 11 bytes ;) Hint: it involves cumulative reduction.

Comment: @Shaggy Did I get your 11 byte solution?

Comment: Seeing as @EmbodimentofIgnorance got that, you can still golf this one to [17 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=OzI2xkKvsFgg1Ky4%2bTI1K1g)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 59 bytes

```php
for($a=A;$i++<26;)echo str_pad('',26-$i),$s=$a++." $s","
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQSbR2tVTK1tW2MzKw1U5Mz8hWKS4riCxJTNNTVdYzMdFUyNXVUim1VErW19ZQUVIqVdJS4lKz//wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## Elixir, 70 bytes

```
r=90..65;for i<-0..25,do: IO.puts for j<-r,do: 65+i-j>-1&&[j,' ']||' '
```

[Try it here](https://repl.it/repls/ButteryHideousSupport)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), <del>125</del> 119 bytes

Not very interesting until I read other answers.

```
for(i in 0..25){
System.write(" "*(25-i))
for(j in 0..i)System.write(" "+String.fromCodePoint(65+i-j))
System.print()
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/Py2/SCNTITNPwUBPz8hUs5oruLK4JDVXr7wosyRVQ0lBSUvDyFQ3U1OTC6QyC6oyUxNdmXZwSVFmXrpeWlF@rnN@SmpAfmZeiYaZqXambhZQM1R5QRFIVJOr9v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Javascript ES6](https://www.javascript.com/), 105 bytes

```js
[..."ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"].forEach((l,i,a)=>console.log(" ".repeat(25-i)+a.slice(25-i).join(" ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) (with GNU exec extension), 58 bytes

```
s/^/bash -c 'echo {Z..A}'/e
:
s/^( *)\S([^\n]+)/\1\2\n&/
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WD9OPymxOENBN1lBPTU5I1@hOkpPz7FWXT@Vy4oLKKuhoKUZE6wRHReTF6utqR9jGGMUk6emz1Xy/z/Xv/yCksz8vOL/ukUA)

---

## Pure [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 71 bytes

```
s/^/ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA/
s/\B/ /g
:
s/^( *)\S([^\n]+)/\1\2\n&/
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WD9OPyoyIjwsNCQ4KDDA38/Xx9vL08PdzdXF2clRn6tYP8ZJX0E/ncsKyIzTUNDSjAnWiI6LyYvV1tSPMYwxislT0@cq@f@f619@QUlmfl7xf90iAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>133</s> <s>130</s> <s>125</s> <s>123</s> 122 bytes

Not the shortest, but I wanted to try to make the output one single string

```
print('\n'.join((25-len(v)//2)*' '+v for v in(''.join(" "+chr(i)for i in range(90,64,-1))[i:52]for i in range(51,-1,-2))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcpBCsIwEEDRqwzdzIxNrI1GaK9iuxCpdkQmJZSAp48Ruurfvr981znoOecliq6Eg@LxHUSJnLefSSlx0zg@IGCd4BkiJCiK21VBVT/mSMJ/kkIQ7/qaqDuZ68XYlvkmvXfjjn1bzFjHpZx/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 30 bytes

```perl
$b[26+--$i]=$_,say"@b"for A..Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lKdrITFtXVyUz1lYlXqc4sVLJIUkpLb9IwVFPL@r//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ØAa⁶ḊÐƤżKƤUY
```

A full program which prints the result

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//w5hBYeKBtuG4isOQxqTFvEvGpFVZ//8)**

#### How?

```
ØAa⁶ḊÐƤżKƤUY - Main Link: no arguments
ØA           - (set left to) uppercase alphabet  say:['A','B','C']
   ⁶         - space character                       ' '
  a          - AND (vectorises)                      [' ',' ',' ',]
     ÐƤ      - for postfixes:
    Ḋ        -   dequeue                             [[' ',' '],[' '],[]]
         Ƥ   - for prefixes (of left=alphabet):
        K    -   join with spaces                    [['A'],['A',' ','B'],['A',' ','B',' ','C']]
       ż     - zip together                          [[[' ',' '],['A']],[[' '],['A',' ','B']],[[],['A',' ','B',' ','C']]]
          U  - upend                                 [[[' ',' '],['A']],[[' '],['B',' ','A']],[[],['C',' ','B',' ','A']]]
           Y - join with newlines                    [[' ',' '],['A'],'\n',[' '],['B',' ','A'],'\n',[],['C',' ','B',' ','A']]
             - implicit, smashing print >>>  A
             -                          >>> B A
             -                          >>>C B A
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>83</s> 82 bytes

(−1 golfing thanks to ceilingcat)

```
main(c){for(char s[99]="",*t=s+98;*--t=c+64,printf("%*s\n",c+++25,t)<52;*--t=32);}
```

Builds the final string from end to beginning, printing all the unfinished versions.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ùivK‼9⌂m¬╚─
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9769764b13397f6daac8c4&i=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 103 bytes

```python
p=-1
x="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
s=""
for a in[0]*26:print(" "*abs(26-p)+" ".join(s:=x[(p:=p+1)]+s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfRDoIgFADQd76C3SeQ6dI219julzgfsDKxghtgYT9PnbdDe1q8O54olEJYtywjmOl8uc63xa73x9N5eoWYtvcn719gEQHY7AM33LrhMFZdrylYlwRwqMwURdfXJNV/zeqtE1FjHgRpJNXKUUUpS/kB)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;Båi Ë¬¸ùBÊ+E
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0LlaSDLrLj5QsorRQ)

```
;Båi Ë¬¸ùBÊ+E
;B                :Uppercase alphabet
  å               :Cumulatively reduce by
   i              :  Prepending
     Ë            :Map each element at 0-based index E
      ¬           :  Split
       ¸          :  Join with spaces
        ù         :  Left pad with spaces to length
         BÊ+E     :    Length of B plus E
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 22 bytes

```
sX26-_.(RAZ@<_Js)M\,26
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbo5S7IKlpSVpuhbbiiOMzHTj9TSCHKMcbOK9ijV9Y3SMzCCSUDULoDQA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
sX26-_.(RAZ@<_Js)M\,26
                  \,26  ; Range of numbers from 1 through 26
                 M      ; Map this function to each:
  26-_                  ;  26 minus function argument
sX                      ;  That many spaces
      .(        )       ;  Concatenate to the following:
         AZ             ;  Uppercase alphabet
           @<_          ;  Slice left of function argument
        R               ;  Reverse
              Js        ;  Join on spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 21 bytes

```
L26PsX25-i.:RAZ@<UiJs
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZbfYzMAoojjEx1M_WsghyjHGxCM72KIXJQJTClAA)

#### Explanation

The guts are very similar to [my Pip `-l` answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267136/16766), but the iterative flagless approach turned out to be one byte shorter (at least until I implement that "center and pad with spaces" operator I've been planning).

```lisp
L26PsX25-i.:RAZ@<UiJs
                      ; s is " ", i is 0, AZ is uppercase alphabet (implicit)
L26                   ; Loop 26 times:
    sX25-i            ;  String of (25-i) spaces
          .:          ;  Concatenate with:
                 Ui   ;   Increment i
             AZ@<     ;   Take that many characters from the front of AZ
            R         ;   Reverse
                   Js ;   Join on spaces
   P                  ;  Print that string
```